# What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?

Tags: packages, big-list

I'm getting the impression from reading the answers written by some of the real experts here that there are quite a few little packages that just tweak LaTeX2e's default behaviour a little to make it more sensible here and there.

Rather than try to pick these up one by one as I read answers to questions (and thus risk missing them), I thought I'd ask up front what LaTeX2e packages people load by default in (almost) every document.

As this is a "big list" question, I'm making it CW.  I don't know if there are standard rules across all SE/SO sites for such questions, but on MathOverflow the rule is generally: one thing (in this case, package) per answer.  I guess that if a couple of packages really do go together then it would be fine to group them.

This is perhaps a little subjective and a little close to the line, so I'll not be offended if it gets closed or voted down!  (But *please* explain why in the comments.)

Also see our community poll question: [“I have used the following packages / classes”](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1574/)

Comment: There are standard rules across all SE sites, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow and follow the links.  The idea is that the answer to a "what are good default packages" question is way too big for a single user to write, so the community helps out. The *one* accepted answer that *everyone* edits has lots of edits from lots of people.  Anton Geraschenko of MO made his own very different interpretation, "post one resource per answer" (http://mathoverflow.net/faq#communitywiki), and we'll have to decide one or the other.

Comment: Personally, I'd find a single list, separated by headings (Ex. Format, Math, Bib,Images, Other for this question), with a list of everyone's packages and how they're different from other packages in the section much more readable and useful. That amsmath is the highest voted just says that the MO community is here in full force.  The less-known, but equally relevant formatting packages linked by Vivi, Joseph, and András are invisible without a lot of scrolling and reading.

Comment: I think the list of one package per answer is a good idea, as we can vote on individual packages...

Comment: My intention was not so much to find an ordering, but rather to find if there are any that I'd never heard of.  It's not working out quite as I'd hoped, but I'm not sure if its possible to fix it at this stage (or worth doing).

Comment: It can be good to have a single answer that is just an index of all the other answers, and accept that, so that it floats to the top.

Comment: @naught101 I'd thought of making into a blog post, actually.  If a single answer then someone else will have to do it since if I do it and accept it then it won't float to the top.

Answer (score 283):

I almost always load [**`microtype`**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype). It plays with ever-so-slightly shrinking and stretching of the fonts and with the extent to which text protrudes into the margins in a way that yields results that look better, that have fewer instances of hyphenation, and fewer overfull hboxes. It doesn't work with `latex`, you have to use `pdflatex` instead. It also works with `lualatex` and (protrusion only) with `xelatex`.

Comment: I use `\usepackage[expansion=false]{microtype}` almost always. Microtype with expansion is a bit too much for me.

Comment: You may want to use `\usepackage[stretch=10]{microtype}`, which allows font expansion up to 1% (default is 2%).

Comment: Can we have an example of with versus without?

Comment: there's a nice example in the documentation for microtype http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf, though it requires adobe acrobat for the inline examples

Comment: [Here](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/pdflatex-microtype/) is another example.

Comment: The only texts for which I don't use `microtype` are those set `raggedright`. It seems to maximally stretch practically all lines. In any case, `ragged2e` then becomes the must include package.

Comment: I sure love the default font of LaTeX. But microtype isn't able to strech that font. What font should I use so i can keep the look and feel? [(Image of the default Font)](https://i.imgur.com/I96R84i.png)

Comment: Here is a superb page of examples with and without microtype: http://www.khirevich.com/latex/microtype/

Comment: Just tested, and the result is superb. Wonderful tip.

Answer (score 230):

The family of [**AMS math packages**](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). At least `amsmath` and `amssymb`. Also `amsthm` if I need theorems and the class I'm using doesn't already define them.

Particularly for writing equations, the AMS packages define a rich set of environments to group and align formulas in many different and useful ways. I also like that it encourages the use of *semantic* commands (e.g. the `cases` environment) over syntactic commands (e.g. a `\left\{` followed by an array).

Its documentation can be found running `texdoc amsldoc` on a command line.

Comment: In particular, `amsthm` provides an easy way to set up different theorem styles, `amsmath` provides the `\text` command, and `amssymb` contains several often-used symbols.

Comment: Also `amsfonts`, which provides some (partial) fonts which are frequently used in math.

Comment: +1 for the (oblique) reference to texdoc.  I only discovered that recently and I wonder how I ever lived without it!

Comment: I believe `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`. There's rarely any need to load it yourself.

Comment: Note that the ams math packages are loaded automatically if you use one of their document classes, such as `amsart`.

Comment: Instead of loading `amsmath` I usually load [**`mathtools`**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools). It is based on `amsmath` and loads it automatically. Moreover it fixes some deficiencies of the `amsmath` package and provides additional useful commands such as `\coloneqq`.

Comment: Do I need it if I use kpfonts or mathpazo?

Answer (score 204):

I use [`hyperref`](http://tug.org/applications/hyperref/) for setting PDF metadata and to create links, both within the document and for clickable URLs.  Even Elsevier has used [`urlbst`](http://nxg.me.uk/dist/urlbst/) to update their bibliography style to support URLs and DOIs; hyperref does the actual work of rendering `url =` and `doi =` BibTeX fields into clickable PDF links.

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before

Answer (score 178):

For citations and bibliographies, [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is the package of my choice. Key points:

- `biblatex` includes a wide variety of built-in citation/bibliography styles (numeric, alphabetic, author-year, author-title, verbose [full in-text-citations], with numerous variants for each one). A number of [custom styles](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib/) have been published.
- Modifications of the built-in or custom styles can be accomplished using LaTeX macros instead of having to resort to the BibTeX programming language.
- `biblatex` offers well-nigh every feature of other bibliography-related LaTeX packages (e.g. multiple/subdivided bibliographies, sorted/compressed citations, entry sets, ibidem functionality, back references). If a feature is not included, chances are high it is on the package authors' to-do list.
- The [`babel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) package is supported, and `biblatex` comes with localization files for about a dozen languages (with the list still growing).
- Although the current version of `biblatex` (2.8a) still allows to use BibTeX as a database backend, by default it cooperates with [Biber](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber) which supports bibliographies using Unicode. Biber (currently at version 1.8) is included in TeX Live and MiKTeX. Many features introduced since `biblatex` 1.1 (e.g., advanced name disambiguation, smart crossref data inheritance, configurable sorting schemes, dynamic datasource modification) are "Biber only".

Comment: Nevertheless one should append about the usage of `biblatex` that some papers do not accept its usage. See: [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/biblatex-submitting-to-a-journal/12179#12179)

Answer (score 152):

The todonotes package is a must have in all my documents.

```
\usepackage{todonotes}
```

The package enables you to insert small notes in the text marking things to do in the document. Something like

```
\todo{Rewrite this answer \ldots}
```

At any location in the document a list of the inserted notes can be generated with the

```
\listoftodos
```

command.

Comment: For multiuser comment support, and configurability with regard to the kinds of notes/themes available, the [fixme](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/fixme.html) package is quite nice (I use it quite regularly).

Comment: `todonotes` also supports colors and missing graphics.

Comment: I find todonote invaluable as I prepare syllabai and course material for the upcoming term. Because I cannot do everything at one sitting I put a todo note whenever i find something I have to wait to do.   I also use it during the semester to highlight to the students anything which was changed after the documents were first published.

Comment: Personally I use an editor which automatically highlights and groups in the "structure" window any comment that begins with %TODO: Works better for me because you don't have anything in your compiled document giving away the fact that it still has TODOs around.

Comment: Has anyone done a comparison between `easy-todo`, `fixme`, `fixmetodonotes`, `todo`, and `todonotes`?

Comment: For me, the nicest part of todonotes is that when I am done, I can remove the usepackage, and if I have forgotten something, LaTeX will scream loudly. Instead, a TODO in a comment may end up [leaking](https://twitter.com/overheardonaph?lang=en)

Answer (score 144):

One package that’s *really* general purpose is [**`nag`**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nag): It doesn’t *do* anything, per se, it just warns when you accidentally use deprecated LaTeX constructs from l2tabu ([English](http://texdoc.net/pkg/l2tabuen) / [French](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l2tabu-french/l2tabufr.pdf) / [German](http://texdoc.net/pkg/l2tabu) / [Italian](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l2tabu-italian/l2tabuit.pdf) / [Spanish](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l2tabu-spanish/l2tabues.pdf) documentation).

From the documentation:

> Old habits die hard. All the same, there are commands, classes and packages which are outdated and superseded. nag provides routines to warn the user about the use of those. As an example, we provide an extension that detects many of the “sins” described in l2tabu.

Therefore, I now always have the following in my header (*before* the `\documentclass`, thanks qbi):

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
```

It’s a bit like having `use strict;` in Perl: a useful best practice.

Comment: Somewhat better is `\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}` _before_ `\documentclass`. The package docu also recommends this.

Comment: This package sounds useful. However, when I tested it with a large project, I started to get the message "Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right." no matter how many times I re-run Latex.

Comment: Your description sure sounds like a package that's really *specific*, not really general purpose ….

Comment: @LSpice How so? It’s very general purpose in that it can/should be included into *every* LaTeX document, rather than only specific types of documents. It’s certainly specific in that it does one specific thing (diagnostics), but by that definition *every* package is specific rather than general-purpose. Clearly not what most people would think about.

Comment: Well, probably my making even one comment, and certainly my making two, was my going beyond usefulness; but to me you are describing something that's widely useful, not something that's general purpose.  Something that's general purpose can, I think, be used to do many things (think of the `amsmath` package, which adds a lot of goodies to all kinds of math environments); something that does one thing isn't general purpose, even if it does that one thing in many circumstances.  (I wouldn't call a watch 'general purpose', for example, even back when people wore them all the time.)

Answer (score 129):

I nearly always use the `tikz` package. Once you learn how to draw with it, you can do almost any vector graphic you need.

Comment: I have always used Inkscape for the production of my vector images, diagrams and whatsoever. Does tikz produce comparable diagrams? How much effort is involved?

Comment: You can produce almost any diagram with Tikz. Check the tikz examples page.

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

However, it is fairly complicated to get the hang on large diagrams since you have to type everything and nearly always you can't see what you are doing. But if you are using a Debian/KDE combination, you can use Ktikz/Qtikz which is really helpful since it compiles tikz code in real time.

Comment: TikZ is awesome with a capital A.  But load it by default?  It takes up a lot of time and space.  I would say only load it if you need it.

Comment: It takes time, but nearly always I find I need to do something with it.

Comment: @levesque: Tikz has a fairly steep learning curve, but it is beautifully documented and provides rich libraries. I find the vector graphics that I produce in tikz to be superior to those I produced in inkscape. It seems easier on my brain to stay in keyboard mode as well.

Answer (score 129):

Another essential package combination is

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
```

The [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package creates much nicer looking tables than the standard latex tables; the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package's ability to create custom columns is invaluable for formatting tabular material on a per-column basis.

Comment: I just discovered booktabs -- it is great!

Comment: @Ben Yes, it's a great package.  If you visit my profile web link you can find my own list of essential packages.

Answer (score 128):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set page margins automatically
```

This is in every document I write (with varying margins, of course.)

Comment: This is generally poor style. The design of the page is pretty involved and lots of thought has went into (La)TeX's default designs. If you're interested in just saving paper, consider the packages `savetrees` or `fullpage`.

Comment: Both `savetrees` and `fullpage` change other things too; Anyway, the point of of the answer is that `geometry` is a must use package, no matter what margins you choose for it. The appropriateness of 1in margins also depends on the kind of documents you produce.

Comment: It is not a must if you use a class from the KOMAscript bundle or memoir.

Comment: @Sveinung but it is a must if you have to comply with certain margins, because your supervisor/advisor/publisher orders you to do so.

Comment: @Skillmon No, because `memoir` and KOMA have their own ways to set margins, so `geometry` isn't needed, which is what Sveinung means, I suppose.

Comment: @AlanMunn KOMA's approach to set the margins is by division. You can't easily set arbitrary margins with `typearea`, as it'll always produce certain ratios (e.g. top margin is half of bottom margin). The result is however beautiful and I'd personally never use `geometry` unless I have to meet other peoples' criterion. For `memoir` you're right though, that one is supposed to have code similar to `geometry`'s.

Comment: @Skillmon Maybe so. I will never use KOMA as its English documentation is abysmal.

Comment: @AlanMunn don't know, I always read the German one, and that one is pretty nice :)

Comment: @AlanMunn And the English one is good enough for a Norwegian :)

Comment: @AlanMunn The KOMA-Script English documentation was completely rewritten last year, and is now quite readable.

Answer (score 124):

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

[`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), for typesetting units and especially for the "S" column type, which allows numbers in tables to be easily aligned, e.g. on the decimal marker.

Comment: `\usepackage[allowlitunits]{siunitx}` is my normal incantation, it allows you to use things like `20\milli\meter` directly in math mode.

Comment: I have evidently never followed through on my plan to read the siunitx manual in depth. I was not aware of the S column type or allowlitunits, thank you!

Answer (score 123):

Since my files nowadays has [UTF-8 character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8), I use this

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX would be my choice for this

Comment: Interesting, must look into those projects.

Comment: Isn't it `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`?

Comment: I've experienced several cases where `utf8x` had a symbol that `utf8` hadn't

Comment: @Olivier: `utf8` is LaTeX base, while `utf8x` comes from the ucs package. So `utf8` is portable.

Comment: [Worth noting this is no longer needed since 2018](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370279/250119). [utf8x has some issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc), if you want Unicode math symbols (which is in my experience most of the differences) I recommend my package `unicode-math-input` but there are [a handful of alternatives](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628285/250119).

Answer (score 88):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

For including figures, rotating or scaling text.  I also use the `\graphicspath` command to specify a subfolder to help organize my figures and so I can easily change between, for example, a set of figures for internal used (with extra info) and final versions for distribution.

Answer (score 84):

The 'rich' document classes such as [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/memoir.html) and [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/koma-script.html) include a lot of functionality that is not available from the LaTeX kernel. So the packages you load when using the article class might be rather different from those when using memoir. A lot of packages that get used by many people with the base classes (things like float, caption, tocbibind and titlesec) are covered by the richer document classes.

Comment: `\begin{gripe}` My problems with these richer document classes are that it makes it very difficult to pick and choose, and that it is a major pain when Big Shot Journal says "please rewrite your document to use _our_ class file" (there's even a journal that won't let you send an accompanying style file).  `\end{gripe}`

Comment: I tend to stick to article + packages, myself, so I can sympathise. All the more reason for me to get on and get LaTeX3 finished, so we can have a good set of abilities out of the box!

Comment: `\begin{joke}` Then stop wasting time here and get on with it! `\end{joke}`

Comment: If only it were that easy :-) If you want to see that things are happening, there is an RSS feed for SVN checkins: http://www.latex-project.org/latex3svn.rss

Comment: That gripe seems a gripe with the journals, rather than with the rich document classes. Also, if you're writing a journal article, memoir doesn't seem like an obvious way to go, if you are going to end up having to conform to some journal's style eventually. Again, that's not an issue with rich document classes, that's just a matter of picking the right tool for the job. And for journal submissions, minimal package requirements and basic document classes seems a good modus operandi

Comment: @JosephWright: even if you finished LaTeX3 tomorrow, how long would it take most journals to convert?..

Comment: @naught101 There is no guarantee that they ever will: it's a question of having 'killer features'. Based on the LaTeX2e experience (moving from 2.09) you are talking at least ten years.

Comment: \newenvironment{letsuseunnecessesarymarkupinourbitchycomments{\begin{letsuseunnecessesarymarkupinourbitchycomments}}{\end{letsuseunnecessesarymarkupinourbitchycomments}}

Answer (score 69):

In addition to many packages already listed here, I always include `mathtools`. It provides implementations of `\mathclap` (and similar commands) as well as nice extensible arrow.

Comment: `\mathclap` is great. I use it to great effect for things like `\sum_{\mathclap{big long thing}}`. (It's also amusingly named with at least one off-color meaning.)

Comment: `\shortintertext` is also provided by the `\mathtools` package and provids tighter vertical spacing compared to `\intertext` from the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 65):

```
\usepackage{lmodern}  % better i18n Postscript version of Knuth's cm fonts
```

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super

Comment: I never use this except for debugging. `\usepackage{cfr-lm}` ...

Answer (score 64):

I can't live without [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) --- pretty-printing (colours, formatting and all) algorithms and code is indispensable --- in pretty much any programming languages and dialects under the sun. Plus, I can import a source file directly from the repository, and the latest version will be automatically rendered.

Comment: I was pleasantly surprised that I could prettyprint MIPS assembly language code with listings! Excellent package.

Answer (score 63):

For papers on the [arXiv](http://www.arxiv.org) (maths, physics and computer science mostly) there's a [list of packages sorted by frequency of use](http://arxmliv.kwarc.info/package_usage.php).

The top twenty packages are:

1. `article`
2. `graphicx`
3. `amssymb`
4. `amsmath`
5. `revtex`
6. `revtex4`
7. `epsfig`
8. `amsfonts`
9. `bm`
10. `latexsym`
11. `amsart`
12. `dcolumn`
13. `amsthm`
14. `graphics`
15. `aastex`
16. `amscd`
17. `epsf`
18. `color`
19. `aa`
20. `times`

Comment: That list is literally pain to my eyes. Loading `bm`?! Use proper bold math characters instead, please, and not poorman's bold. `times`? Outdated since ages, use `mathptmx` or `XITS Math` instead. I'll stop here...

Comment: @Ingo arXiv has been created in 1991 and some papers haven't been updated since then!

Comment: @Ingo [`bm` package seems okay though](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/bm-package-versus-boldsymbol)? It only fallback to pmb in extreme cases.

Answer (score 61):

The package [`xspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace) lets you define commands that don't eat up whitespace after them.  So you can define an abbreviation like

`\newcommand{\sA}{\mathcal{A}\xspace}`

and then you can type `objects of \sA are called widgets` instead of `objects of \sA\ are called widgets`.

Comment: That's one I use so much that I forget it's not part of the main code!

Comment: On comp.text.tex there's a series of messages "xspace and italic correction" about spacing inconsistencies created by xspace. There, Will Robertson suggested "delimited macros" as an alternative to xspace. Using \newcommand* only to ensure that no existing command is overriden, the above example would look like this:

`\newcommand*{\sA}{}\def\sA/{\mathcal{A}}`

To quote Will Robertson: "In the source you must always type "\foo/" [here: "\sA/"] (or TeX will throw an error), and spaces after it won't be gobbled."

Comment: For me, having to write `\sA/` every time would be even worse than having to write `\sA\ ` every time.  The only advantage I can see to `\sA/` is that you wouldn't have to remember to delete the ending backslash when it's followed by punctuation.

Comment: The main advantage of `\sa/` is that an error message will occur if you happen to forget the closing slash. On the contrary, if you happen to forget the closing backslash of `\sA\ `, you'll end with gobbled space without noticing it.

Comment: I used `xspace` one time in a paper with other authors. It was a huge pain since some macros didn't behave like others. It led to all sort of confusion, especially when thinks like `\foo bar` no long work as you expect because `\foo`'s definition ends with `\xspace`. I've never tried `\foo/`. The main advantage I see with that is if your macro is `\m/`...

Comment: I don't *especially* like the look of `\sA/` but I can't think of a better delimiter to use. Perhaps a semicolon would be fine (after HTML): `\sA;`. My personal belief is that non-delimited macros without arguments (i.e., the ones that gobble spaces) are just plain wrong for document commands because of the spacing problems. Even experienced LaTeX authors trip up with them.

Comment: To be consistent, I just always type `\sA{}`.

Answer (score 52):

First line of the document should be

```
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\documentclass{...}
```

, which fixes a few things in the LaTeX2e kernel.

Due to LaTeX's stability policy, these corrections have not been incorporated into the LaTeX2e kernel, but this package does things most people would agree are bugfixes. So to load this package is always recommended *for newly created documents*. The corrections have no commonalities, but [the package's description](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) has a nice summary:

> - ensure one-column floats don't get ahead of two-column floats;
> - correct page headers in twocolumn documents;
> - stop spaces disappearing in moving arguments;
> - allowing `\fnsymbol` to use text symbols;
> - allow the first word after a float to hyphenate;
> - `\emph` can produce caps/small caps text;
> - bugs in `\setlength` and flushbottom.

---

### EDIT 27.01.2016:

This package is obsolete for LaTeX releases after 2015. See [latexrelease.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/latexrelease.pdf).

Comment: It should be `RequirePackage{fixltx2e}` as first line of you'require document, even before the document class, see http://www.texdev.net/2014/12/28/fixing-latex2e/

Comment: really should be an argument to documentclass.

Comment: `fixltx2e` is not required with releases after 2015(fixltx2e) All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.

Answer (score 45):

I use [`url`](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) to typeset urls.

Answer (score 34):

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
```

I much prefer no indentation and space between paragraphs, so the [parskip](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package is a must for me!

Comment: Have a look at the KOMA-Script-classes - they include a parskip option that is more powerful than the package of the same name.

Comment: @lockstep, but if `parskip` is all you want, surely loading all of `KOMA-Script` is overkill for that ….

Answer (score 34):

For quickly setting multicolumn text in a single column document, the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package is another package that I use all the time.

```
\usepackage{multicol}
```

Answer (score 32):

I almost always use the `enumitem` package, which makes it much easier to make modifications to lists (especially `enumerate` lists). Most notably, changing the labels to something like (i), (ii), (iii) [no period] with this package is as easy as

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item The first item
    \item The second item
\end{enumerate}
```

Furthermore, the code above will automatically get nesting right.  Before I started using this package, my preamble always included the awkward macro (necessary to change the references and eliminate the extra period in the list itself)

```
\newcommand{\setenumroman}{%
    \renewcommand{\theenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}%
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}%
}
```

which would break if I ever used it for a nested list (all the `enumi`s would have to be changed to `enumii`s, if I understand correctly).

The `enumitem` package is quite flexible; another option I sometimes use is `[wide]`, which makes a list look like part of the body of the text (with numbers/labels at the beginning of relevant paragraphs).

Comment: If someone only want the feature of changing labels, easier will be to use the `enumerate` package. Then you could simply write `\begin{enumerate}[(i)]`. But enumitem package gives a lot more flexibility including allowing the items to appear in a line.

Comment: With the `[shortlabels]` option, `enumitem` allows the same shorter syntax as the `enumerate` package that was mentioned in the above comment. So you can write `\begin{enumerate}[(i)]` as well.

Answer (score 28):

Nothing surprising here: I use [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/natbib.html), [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/hyperref.html) and [hypernat](http://ftp.uoi.gr/pub/tex/help/Catalogue/entries/hypernat.html) together.

**Natbib** for referencing.

**Hyperref** adds bookmarks for sections and lists and turns references and urls into links.

**Hypernat** allows natbib and hyperref to work together.  --  **Note (added 2015/02/11)**: `natbib` and `hyperref` have been working together just fine for at least ten years. `hypernat` is no longer needed for any TeX distribution with a vintage more recent than ca 2002.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `hypernat` is superfluous these days. With only loading `natbib` and `hyperref` I get references as [1-5] with both  1 and 5 being hyperlinks.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't even know about `hypernat` until I saw this answer.  I have been using `hyperref` and `natbib` for a while and reference links and backlinks always worked for me.  Is there some extra functionality that `hypernat` adds?

Comment: I had a problem once, found out about natbib, and have been using it ever since, so it is possible it is superfluous and I didn't even know. I will have to test it out and get back to you guys if I find something.

Comment: And? Was it superfluous in 2010? Is it now? ;)

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye - `hypernat` was superfluous (and potentially troublesome) back in 2010 and in 2012, and it continues to be superfluous as of 2015.

Answer (score 28):

To use the palatino font (it's just a nice looking font)

```
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
```

Note that the old `palatino` package is deprecated.

Comment: never use \usepackage{palatino}, see l2tabu. the current way to use Palatino is \usepackage{mathpazo}

Comment: What is l2tabu?

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/

Comment: You should probably also load mathpazo with the `[sc]` option to get real small caps and better kerning.

Comment: Depending on taste, you may want to use `[osf]` instead of `[sc]` to get [old style numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures) as well as the real small caps and better kerning. I for one find old style numerals prettier and classier than lining figures in text mode (using `[osf]` will keep lining figures in math mode).

Comment: According to this the LaTeX font catalogue, one should increase the leading when using `mathpazo`. http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/urwpalladio/

Comment: In 2020, you probably want to load either TeX Gyre Pagella Math, or `newpxmath`.

Answer (score 28):

I almost always find myself using a [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment as opposed to the regular `tabular` environment, as it allows for greater dynamism in column widths.

Answer (score 26):

To make sure you have ISO formated dates (YYYY-MM-DD).

```
\usepackage[english]{isodate}
```

or

```
\usepackage{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{-}
\newcommand{\todayiso}{\the\year \dateseparator \twodigit\month \dateseparator \twodigit\day}
```

Answer (score 23):

Another package I use is [`float`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float). It allows for the placement `H` for floats, which is somewhat equivalent to `h!`, but a bit stronger, making sure the figure or table goes exactly where I want it to be.

Comment: Actually not equivalent to `h!` at all. `h!` floats still "float"- they can be moved around by LaTeX in an attempt to optimize the document layout.  Figures using the `H` specifier are not floats at all, they are treated like one big character and are put exactly where they appear in the text.

Comment: @Sharpie: you are ignoring the word "somewhat" :P Still, your point is valid, thanks!

Comment: I did consider the word somewhat.  However, in my opinion the only similarity between the two is the fact that they are used as float specifiers.  Beyond that, both specifiers produce completely different effects.

Comment: @Sharpie: maybe I should link to the source of the (mis)information? http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures (see the last row of the table)

Comment: @Vivi I fixed that entry of the wikibook.

Answer (score 21):

For mathematical texts I instead use `amsmath` & Co. One very useful package is `onlyamsmath`. I load it as

```
\usepackage[all,warning]{onlyamsmath}
```

So it looks for `$$..$$`, `eqnarray` and produces a warning if some of them are used. If you left out `warning`, it will result in an error and compile will stop. This package is normally very useful if you edit a text with many authors.

Answer (score 20):

*Edited by doncherry: Removed packages mentioned in separate answers.*

<s>The complete header</s> Part of my header for most of my documents looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,draft,parskip=half*,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ifthen}
```

For some things I need `if`-`then`-constructs. This package provides an easy way to realise it.

```
\usepackage{index}
```

For generating an index.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

`xcolor` is needed by several packages. For some historical reason I load it manually.

```
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
```

`nicefrac` allows typesetting fractions like 1/2. It is sometimes more readable than `\frac`.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[intlimits,leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,warning]{onlyamsmath}
```

This package warns if non-`amsmath`-environments are used.

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fixmath}
```

Provides ISO conform greek letters.

```
\usepackage[euro]{isonums}
```

Defines comma as decimal delimiter.

```
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
```

for Theorems, definitions and stuff.

```
\usepackage{paralist}
```

Improves enumerate and itemize. Also provides some compact environments.

```
\usepackage{svn}
```

I work with VCS and svn displays some informations (keywords) from SVN.

```
\usepackage{ellipsis}
```

corrects `\dots`

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
```

These are the definitions for absolute value and norm.

```
\SVN $LastChangedRevision$
\SVN $LastChangedDate$
```

Comment: "one thing (in this case, package) per answer"

Comment: Could you break this up into multiple answers please, so they can be voted on? Having a dozen answers is ok!

Comment: Excellent list with helpful commentary. I will add the one for old and deprecated things to my list. Thanks!

Comment: It is usually recommended to load `hyperref` last.

Answer (score 19):

This has been mentioned in some of the “big answers”, but thought it deserved special attention. Probably most documents should include:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

This is to [resolve some deficiencies and inconsistencies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71517/do-i-need-fontenc-and-inputenc) of the default OT1 font encoding; while improving the support of special characters (e.g. the ability to copy&paste from the generated pdf document).

Answer (score 17):

I save my documents in an SVN repository. The [svn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/svn) package helps to extract some informations out of the version control system. The document has somewhere a hint what revision number and what date it is. For this you have to set svn keywords and declare in your LaTeX document what you need:

```
\SVN $LastChangedRevision$
\SVN $LastChangedDate$
```

Wihtin the document you can refer to that information with `\SVNLastChangedRevision` and `\SVNDate`.

Comment: Do you know if you can you do that with hg?

Comment: I don't work with hg (or just began a few days ago :-)). So I have no idea if it does.

Comment: Also consider svn-multi which allows you to access more svn data tat I use in version footers.

Answer (score 17):

A nice commenting environment is provided by the package:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
```

For debugging purposes I find this package indispensable. Before I found this package I would have to enter % before each line I wished to comment. The environment works as follows:

```
\begin{comment}
Text in this environment will be ignored by LaTeX.
\end{comment}
```

The packages

```
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcomment}
```

provide even greater commenting capabilities (i.e. the ability to selectively typeset certain environments) though I personally haven't had much use for these extended features.

Comment: In any decent editor, you can easily comment out/in several lines at once. Due to that, I find the usefulness of the `comment` environment greatly reduced – i.e. I don’t use it at all.

Comment: I simply use `\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}`.  Put `\comment{` before the block and `}` after to comment out any part of the file.

Comment: I was absolutely amazed to find out that Kile actually natively supports this and thus displays everything in the `comment` environment as if commented out by `%`.

Answer (score 15):

As long as this list is, [minted](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) is missing. For code syntax highlighting it works really well and includes the long list of languages of [pygments](http://pygments.org/languages/). The pieces of code end up looking like this:

```
\begin{minted}{language}  
code
\end{minted}
```

In Beamer it requires frames to be marked as [fragile], and it takes some skill to set it up on Windows. But the results are well worth the effort.

Comment: Could you tell us about its advantages compared to `lstlisting` which seems to be the most commonly used syntax highlighting package?

Comment: @Christian: the main difference is that you can tap directly into pygments, which is a (very) well maintained source for syntax colouring for many languages and is used in many places other than LaTeX.  

There is a full discussion on the differences between lstlisting and minted here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102596/minted-vs-texments-vs-verbments,

Answer (score 14):

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
```

I use it for highly customisable verbatim. The abstract of the [package documentation](ftp://tug.ctan.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf) reads:

> This package provides very sophisticated facilities for reading and writing verbatim
>   TeX code. Users can perform common tasks like changing font family and
>   size, numbering lines, framing code examples, colouring text and conditionally
>   processing text.

Here's an example using the `SaveVerbatim` environment in combination with the `\fcolorbox` command:
[image]

Answer (score 13):

Usually I write German texts. We have new and old rules for spelling. The package [hyphsubst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/hyphsubst.html) provides some new hyphenation pattern. That's why I load it in addition to `babel`:

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
```

Comment: Is this something that is still needed in 2019?

Answer (score 13):

I'm not just feigning surprise when I say I'm shocked that such an incredibly useful package set as `xparse/expl3` (the latter is loaded by the former) hasn't been mentioned yet.  I invariably find myself typing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
```

to begin a document.

Comment: So, what does it do?

Comment: with `xparse`, one can define commands and environments with multiple optional arguments before, between, and after mandatory arguments. Several new type of arguments can be defined, starred commands, and much more.

Comment: Somebody else has also posted this later on (but with more/different detail) as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238482/78134

Answer (score 12):

*Edited by doncherry: Removed packages mentioned in separate answers.*

I use TeX for a variety of documents: research papers, lectures/tutorials, presentations, miscellaneous documents (some in Japanese).  Each of these different uses, requires different packages.

Depending on my mood, I like to use different fonts.  A particular nice combination for mathematics papers is

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % better treatment of accented words
\usepackage{eulervm}   % Zapf's Euler fonts
\usepackage{tgpagella} % TeXGyre Pagella fonts
```

For references,...

```
\usepackage[notref,notcite]{showkeys} % useful when writing the paper
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite} % [1,2,3,4,5] --> [1-5]  useful in hep-th!
\usepackage{hyperref} % hyperlinks, metadata,...
```

For lecture notes (again mathematical) I often like to section the document into "lectures" instead of sections and to add some colours to the titles,....  To do this it's useful to use

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % fancy headers
\usepackage{titlesec} % to change how sections are displayed
\usepackage{color}    % to be able to do this in colour
```

and I also like to decorate using some silly glyphs, for which these fonts are useful:

```
\usepackage{wasysym,marvosym,pifont}
```

and also box equations and other things

```
\usepackage{fancybox,shadow}
```

I like adding pictures, whence

```
\usepackage[rflt]{floatflt}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure,epic,eepic}
```

You may want to hide the answers to tutorial exercises, problems,... and this can be achieved with

```
\usepackage{version,ifthen} % ifthen allows controlling exclusions
```

I use XeLaTeX for documents containing Japanese, which works better with

```
\usepackage{fontspec} % makes it very easy to select fonts in XeLaTeX
\usepackage{xunicode} % accents
```

Comment: As the question suggested, could you write an answer per package/topic and explain what these packages do or why do you need them?

Comment: can you please add comments like `\ usepackage{foo} % to get following features` within your code?

Comment: Sorry -- misread the format of the question.  I'll break my answer up later today.

Comment: To avoid breaking them up _all_ the way, you could try grouping them a little (say, if there's one package that you wouldn't consider using without another one then put them together).

Comment: @Andrew: Why avoid breaking them up all the way? We'd probably end up with more pages, but I really like the many tiny discussions of packages in this question, which lead to concise tips how to implement a certain package optimally etc. Should this be discussed on meta?

Comment: Do I need that combination for math or can I rely just on a single package such as kpfonts or mathpazo?

Answer (score 12):

This question assumes you are making a LaTeX document for personal use. If you are planning to submit the document to a journal, it's safer to avoid using too many unusual classes, because they may be incompatible with the journal's LaTeX classes or may be incompatible with the style that the journal will impose on your paper. Very common packages like amsthm are usually safe. (I would leave this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet.)

Comment: Yes and no.  Given that I rarely know what paper it is intended for when I start writing a paper, and given how useful some of these packages are, I include them all and try to get away with it!  Sometimes I'm successful, sometimes I need to include the package .sty file along with my submission.

Answer (score 12):

I also find package `lipsum` fun to use. It lets you generate several versions of *lorem ipsum* placeholder text to see what your document would look like.

Comment: Very useful when preparing drafts or templates but not only.

Comment: `blindtext` is much more mighty, it has several languages and can use some example math.

Answer (score 10):

For the natural scientists among us, the package `mhchem` makes it very easy to typeset chemical symbols and chemical equations.

Comment: What about the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) bundle and the [`chemnum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemnum) package?

Answer (score 9):

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{luximono}
```

which is a fixed-width font which supports boldface. This is useful when typesetting source code.

Answer (score 9):

```
\usepackage{docmute}
```

I use this in my syllabus preparation as I can make each of the subordinate documents fully standalone, yet do a complete compile of everything at once to verify I have all the corrections made.

It does require that all of the preambles are identical.

This then allows me to work only on one course syllabus or schedule or homework assignments with very fast compiles.  Also during the semester I can do corrections on individual documents.

My main document preamble is

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\input{commonpreamble}
\usepackage{docmute}
\begin{document}
```

And the subordinate documents have this preamble

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\input{commonpreamble}
\begin{document}
```

Notice: Only one master document and the `\usepackage{docmute}` is only in that file.

Also all subordinate document must be only loaded with `\input` or `\include` from the main document.  Only one level down is allowed.

I keep one copy of the preamble as commonpreamble.  And all files are kept in one folder.  This system works very well with Texmaker or TexStudio as the structure of the document is always displayed regardless of choosing a "Master Document".

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/docmute

Answer (score 7):

I just discovered the `xparse` package. It lets you define more flexible macros with more than one optional argument. I used it to make a very general partial derivative function.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\pder}{ O{} O{} m }{\frac{\partial^{#2}#1}{\partial#3^{#2}}}
```

**Example**

`\pder{x}` will give you

[image]

`\pder[f]{x}` will give you

[image]

`\pder[f][3]{x}` will give you

[image]

Comment: Also posted as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121259/78134

Comment: You currently have `\pder[f][3]{x}` yielding $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$.  Is that a typo, or is the numbering really off by one?

Comment: @LSpice Probably a typo. It been a long time since i made this post. But do try it out and let me know.

Answer (score 7):

It has been forgotten the excellent `tcolorbox` package which allows to customize the boxes, to create customized box environments, box commands, backups.

Its possibilities are very great, its doc is about 500 pages long, but since I use it, the writing of my handouts has become much easier.

[tcolorbox – Coloured boxes, for LATEX examples and theorems, etc](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)

Answer (score 6):

When using class `book`, I always load package [`emptypage`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/emptypage).

It needs no particular skill since it doesn't introduce any new command to use, it removes headers and footers from empty pages at the end of chapters just by adding `\usepackage{emptypage}` in your preamble.

The default option is `odd`.

Answer (score 6):

In almost every document I use the `csquotes` package in combination with `babel`. The handling of quotations with `\enquote{}` and the flexibility of changing the way the quotation marks look like is very convenient. See for example, the answer to the question [Quotation Mark Pairing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401088/quotation-mark-pairing/401091#401091).

Answer (score 5):

```
 \usepackage{etex}
```

to be able to include e.g. TikZ without strange errors.

UPDATE: not needed with LaTeX releases since 2015 (source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186594/1340).

Comment: I'm curious about this one. Can you give an example?

Comment: Todd: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7896/no-room-for-a-new-dimen-when-including-tikz

Answer (score 5):

I usually use `relsize` package. It's easy to use it. It changes the font size of part of  your text. Just type `\relsize{x}` where x is the number of steps you want to move through the hierarchy of font sizes.

Comment: it's a mystery to me why relsizes are not the default size changing commands.  probably historical.

Answer (score 4):

The following command *before* the `\documentclass` command permits Computer Modern fonts at arbitrary sizes: `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}`.

Answer (score 4):

I always use

```
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools} % sophisticated equation arrays
```

It offers a sophisticated environment for formatting equation arrays,`IEEEeqnarray` and also offers a few other constructions. I don't use the traditional `eqnarray`s any more. I usually set the option `[retainorgcmds]` because it prevents the package from overwriting the `itemize`, `enumerate` and `description` definitions.

Check out [How to Typeset Equations in LaTeX](http://moser.cm.nctu.edu.tw/manuals.html). The author gives some good examples of how and why to use this package instead of the traditional ones. *The Not So Short
Introduction to LaTeX 2ε* also mentions the package in section 3.5.2. This section actually seems to be a copy of the first link ;)

Answer (score 4):

No one mention [**`tabulary`**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary).

Sometimes  I make tables with  multiline cells in several columns, where the total width must be just `\textwidth`. Use `tabular` with `p{}` columns here is a pain since one must take into account `\tabcolsep`.

For this, the sibling `tabularx` (cited in another answer) could make a good work ( X columns take all the available space), but often I need columns weighted according to the amount of text rather  and with different alignments, but `X` columns of `tabularx` share equally that space.

Instead, `tabulary` allow the use   `L`, `C`, `R` and `J` columns o automatic variable width. Not always a column layouts as `LLCRL` produce the desired result but since it is possible mix L,C,R columns with basic types (`l`,`r`,`c`,`p{}`, `m{}`...) find the best fit (i.e., some like `Lcp{5em}RL`) is a child play.

Answer (score 3):

```
\usepackage{mciteplus}
```

Allows you to combine multiple references: `\cite{refa, *refc, *refc, refd}` will produce one references with `refa`, `refb`, and `refc` combined (if they are not used independently elsewhere).

Comment: BTW: `natbib` supports this feature too. See p.19 in the documentation http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf

Comment: There is a similar `\cites` command in `amsrefs`.

Answer (score 3):

When I'm writing package documentation using `ltxdoc` it likes using three columns for the index. I'd prefer two. I fix it with [the `idxlayout` package](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/idxlayout/idxlayout.pdf):

```
\usepackage[columns=2]{idxlayout}
```

Answer (score 3):

I always load the package `xy` to produce diagrams.

Also `tikz` to draw figures.

Comment: I use `tikz-cd` to get commutative diagrams drawn with `tikz` with a syntax highly reminiscent of the `xy` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I include: `\usepackage{outlines}` in my preamble.  [`outlines`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/outlines) is a quick and easy way to generate hierarchically embedded lists.  Especially useful when I'm drafting up a paper (I like to outline it) or if I'm quickly typing up notes, e.g., at a conference.

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example as a demo and a picture of the output?

Answer (score 3):

I am using the [chemfig](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) and [chemmacros](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=de) packages everyday and they are great for drawing chemical structures and reaction schemes. Both are really good documented and play nice together.

[image: example from manual]

There are also nice third party tools like [mol2chemfig](https://ctan.org/pkg/mol2chemfig) for faster structure drawing instead of writing every bond and atom on your own. ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238760/simpler-way-to-create-chemical-graphs-using-chemfig))

Just to mention another package for chemistry, one could also use [XyMTex](http://xymtex.com/fujitas3/xymtex/indexe.html) but heterocyclic compounds look quite ugly.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised that nobody mentioned the packages:

- `physics` which offers numerous commands to make typing of physics equations faster, simpler and equations easier to read. See the [docs](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf)
- `cleveref` gives nice commands for easier referencing within the document. Note, this package is to be **loaded after `hyperref`** See also the [docs](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf)

Comment: The `physics` package is not very popular, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471532/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471563/ for example

Answer (score 2):

Very often a requirement for the documents I write is that the font should be Times (or Times New Roman), so the package I use to set the main roman font to Times and acceptable math is `mathptmx`.

Recently, I have experimented with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` but, personally, I do not like the design of some symbols and there are a few cases where the spacing between characters is too tight.

For personal use I set the font to New Century Schoolbook and Fourier (for math) with the `fouriernc` package.

Comment: I use the `newtxmath` in conjunction with  `libertine`, and love it. It is great to have upright Greek letters, which fits better to the font as the letters from the `upgreek` package do. Also the upright `\partial` is great, because operators in mathematic should be written upright.

Answer (score 2):

`pageslts`: for being able to refer to the last page of a document

Answer (score 1):

The [ctable](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ctable/ctable.pdf) package is great for typesetting beautiful tables in academic documents. Makes it much simpler and consistent, and the support for marks is awesome.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts

Answer (score 0):

I have a whole slew of commands that that provide a nice short hand for standard idioms of mine. (and which if I ever share tex source would make someone grumpy if i made it a package)

So the meta habit is: whatever personal short hands you think would be nice, have them defined at the top of your template file!

Answer (score 0):

I always end up loading the same packages, some of which were suggested by some answers to this question, such as `hyperref`, `amsmath`, `nag`, `etoolbox`, `xparse`, and others.

I created a style file `latexdev.sty` that I use in almost all my notes and publications, which loads all these standard packages:

https://github.com/olivierverdier/latexdev

Answer (score 0):

The [epstopdf](https://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf?lang=en) provides ability to include the EPS file so that to con­verts an EPS file to an en­cap­su­lated PDF file. The re­sult­ing file suit­able for in­clu­sion by pdfTeX as an im­age. The script is adapted to run both on Win­dows and on Unix-alike sys­tems.

Answer (score 0):

[utf8x]{inputenc}, [T1]{fontenc} and babel are in all documents.
hyperref, biblatex, graphicx and xspace and the ams family are those I rememnber from the top of my head to be in most documents.