# What are the most popular LaTeX packages?

Tags: packages, best-practices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex)

As subject.  What are the most popular LaTeX packages?

Comment: Definitly a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex

Comment: Also rather subjective and without a definite answer (except if someone does a large-scale study). You might want to ask a more specific question.

Comment: The nice thing about this question is that someone has done a large-scale study, as can be seen by following the link.

Answer (score 4):

For papers on the [arXiv](http://www.arxiv.org) (maths, physics and computer science mostly) there's a [list of packages sorted by frequency of use](http://arxmliv.kwarc.info/package_usage.php).

The top twenty packages are:

1. `article`
2. `graphicx`
3. `amssymb`
4. `amsmath`
5. `revtex`
6. `revtex4`
7. `epsfig`
8. `amsfonts`
9. `bm`
10. `latexsym`
11. `amsart`
12. `dcolumn`
13. `amsthm`
14. `graphics`
15. `aastex`
16. `amscd`
17. `epsf`
18. `color`
19. `aa`
20. `times`

Comment: You could add that answer to the already existing question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex) as this one will probably be closed rather soon.

Comment: The two questions have very different answers, and so can't be duplicates of each other.