# Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?

Tags: packages, hyperref, incompatibility

The `hyperref` documentation says: "Make sure it comes last of your loaded packages". The reason is that it redefines many LaTeX commands. It's a rule of thumb that helps to avoid errors.

However, there are exceptions, for instance the `amsrefs` user's guide notes that `amsrefs` has to be loaded *after* `hyperref`.

To avoid problems when adding hypertext functionality: do you know further such exceptions?

Comment: Someone should write a package that takes a set of package names and loads them in the best order. Not me, though.

Comment: My template (http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/latextemplate/) tries to do exactly this. It is full of `\ExecuteAfterPackage`sequences. Although I have to check with all the packages meantioned here!

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech, could you please repost your template? The link seems dead.

Comment: Indeed, I changed the repository. It is now available for download at https://code.google.com/p/latexthesistemplate/downloads/list

Comment: @JimHefferon: Done by mhelvens: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123174/4918

Comment: @JimHefferon there’s the `pkgloader` package: i’ve only speed-read the docs, but it looks a good step towards automation for the job.  (i assume it’s a never-ending process, keeping it up-to-date, but it's looking good.)

Comment: The recent link of the template by @matthias-pospiech is http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/latex/vorlagen/allgemein/

Comment: @Koppor: That is correct the repository however is (again changed, since google shut down code.google) https://github.com/pospiech/latex

Answer (score 137, accepted):

- `cleveref`

Many others are documented in section 11.1 of the `hyperref` [manual](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html#x1-6500011.1). Some are more complex than simply loading after `hyperref`. Here are some more common ones...

- `amsrefs`
- `float` before `hyperref` before  `algorithm`
- `chappg`
- `sidecap`
- `linguex`

Comment: Thanks, also for pointing to the README. hyperref has an extensive README. Though, some packages like cleveref, breakurl and others mentioned here weren't listed there. I'll check and perhaps send a note to the author, perhaps he would like to add them.

Comment: Good idea to contact the author. Heiko is generally very responsive about this things.

Comment: Thanks for improving my answer by adding the packages with options! (I already gave +1 to your answer, thus I cannot "more-upvote" here.)

Comment: As a note, sidecap  no longer has to be loaded after hyperref (as of 2002/05/24 v1.5h according to the linked document.)

Comment: I really think that this is an example of one of the weaknesses of LaTex. Very frustrating behavior.

Answer (score 96):

- [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry): From the [User manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf):

  > With `mag <> 1000`, no `truedimen` and `hyperref`, `hyperref` should be loaded before `geometry`. Otherwise the resulted PDF size will become wrong.
- [`robustindex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/robustindex)
- [`hypdestopt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hypdestopt), [`hypcap`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hypcap), [`hypbmsec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hypbmsec)
- [`attachfile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile)
- [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe), [`showidx`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/showidx.sty) (which disables the `\href`s in the index but in this loading order at least documents compile at all)
- [`uri`](http://ctan.org/pkg/uri), [`pageslts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts), [`regstats`](http://ctan.org/pkg/regstats)
- [`refcheck`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcheck)

and probably also further packages with `\RequirePackage{hyperref}`. A quick search in TeX Live 2011 resulted in this list:

- [`amsrefs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsrefs)
- [`attachfile2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2)
- `bugtracker` (part of [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots))
- [`classicthesis`](http://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis)
- [`doi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/doi)
- `dtx-style` (part of [`thuthesis`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thuthesis))
- [`eforms`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eforms)
- [`exerquiz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exerquiz)
- [`hypgotoe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hypgotoe)
- [`insdljs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/insdljs)
- [`ltxdockit`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxdockit)
- [`opcit`](http://ctan.org/pkg/opcit)
- [`prerex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/prerex)
- [`rec-thy`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rec-thy)
- [`tdclock`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tdclock)
- [`toptesi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/toptesi)
- `ydoc-code` and `ydoc-desc` (both part of [`ydoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ydoc); note, that `ydoc-doc` contains `\hypersetup` without loading `hyperref`)
  )

Packages with `\RequirePackage[<some option(s)>]{hyperref}`:

- [`beamerbasearticle`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)
- [`bidituftehyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bidi)
- [`chextras`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chextras)
- [`cmpj`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cmpj)
- [`dtk-pdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dtk)
- [`easy-todo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/easy-todo)
- [`hep`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hep)
- [`hrefhide`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hrefhide)
- [`ifmslide`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifmslide)
- [`lstdoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)
- [`ocgtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ocgtools)
- [`pdfcomment`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment)
- [`pdfscreen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfscreen)
- [`pdfx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfx)
- [`rvdtx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/grid)
- [`strukdoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/struktex)
- [`ucshyper`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode)

Comment: According to `texdoc geometry`, it should read: With `mag <> 1000`... I have edited the reply.

Comment: @user946850: Yes, there is a "not equal" sign in the pdf which died during copy & paste. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: This may not be necessary any more for `showkeys`, as `hyperref` now has support for `showkeys`.  See pages 207-208 of `hyperref.pdf`.

Comment: Well, I'm partly wrong.  `\bibitem` doesn't show its key if `showkeys` is loaded before `hyperref`.  On the other hand, `\autopageref` gets broken if `showkeys` comes _after_ `hyperref`.  What to do?  Maybe a bug report.

Comment: could you update this to texlive 2017, if there are any changes?

Answer (score 53):

Other common ones include

- `bookmark`
- `glossaries`

Comment: Thanks! glossaries isn't even mentioned in manual or README. bookmark is recommended in the manual though without telling the loading order.

Comment: Hi Stefan, although `glossaries` can be loaded before `hyperref`, you have to jump through extra hoops to make it work quite as well. Nicola isn't terribly explicit about this in her `glossaries` manual, although in her only coded snippet involving `hyperref` she loads `glossaries` 2nd of all (see p. 69). For me, I've achieved much better results with glossary autohyperlinks loading the two packages in this order too.

Comment: @Stefan: Actually, the glossaries manual has this to say: “If you load the hyperref or html packages prior to loading the glossaries package, commands such as `\glslink` and `\gls` […] will automatically have hyperlinks …”

Answer (score 22):

I experienced problem with the package `ellipsis` when loaded before `hyperref`.

In addition, as Joseph Wright writes here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64605/9632, `cmap` has to be loaded after `hyperref`.

Answer (score 16):

The [tabularx](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package is definitely one of the candidates. Otherwise links to footnotes are prevented.

Comment: `tabularx` should be loaded after or before hyperref?  I'm loading it before and doesn't seem to give me any errors, and both documentations say nothing about it...

Comment: I doubt this is valid. Could you provide proof?

Comment: I can verify that `tabularx`, loaded before `hyperref` causes trouble when you use footnotes in tables that are put inside a `minipage`.

Comment: Since loading `tabularx`/`xltabular` after `hyperref` the warning "pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{table.X.X}) has been already used" is gone, too.

Answer (score 11):

`cleveref` is one.

Answer (score 10):

Although not mentioned in its manual,

- `footnotebackref`

loads `hyperref` without options before beginning its work. On that account, it might make better sense in documents to load `footnotebackref` second of the two.

Answer (score 10):

[`minitoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc)

From the [`minitoc` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/minitoc/minitoc.pdf) (section **2.17 Using the `hyperref` package with `minitoc`**; emphasis added):

> Since version #31, `minitoc` works correctly with the powerful `hyperref` package [...] If you add the loading of the `hyperref` package to a document yet using `minitoc`, you will get error message about
>   spurious closing braces. Just let finish the LaTeX run, then re-LaTeX the document. There will be no problem if you remove the loading of `hyperref` and add it again: the problem occurs
>   only when upgrading from `minitoc` #30 to `minitoc` #31 (or higher) with a document already
>   processed and adding `hyperref` at the same time! It seems better to process the document
>   with `minitoc` #31 (or higher) without `hyperref`, then with `hyperref`, because some internal
>   commands written into the auxiliary files have been modified. **If used, the `hyperref` package
>   must be loaded before `minitoc`.**

Answer (score 9):

One more is

- [`hypernat`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypernat)

To quote its README:

> Allows `hyperref` package and the natbib package with options `numbers` and `sort&compress` to work together. This means that multiple sequential citations (e.g [3,2,1]) will be compressed to [1-3], where the '1' and the '3' are (color-)linked to the bibliography.

Comment: As far as I can tell, hypernat is obsolete. You shouldn't load it either after or before hyperref. With modern versions of natbib and hyperref the sort&compress works and is linked without loading any other packages.

Comment: You're right... that's one less package I can load now.

Answer (score 8):

I had some funny behaviour with `pgfpages` until I moved it after `hyperref`, but I'm not sure exactly what the issue was. I'm trying to replicate it, but I can't seem to get it to work at all now!

Answer (score 7):

Another package is [`apacite`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite).

See also http://promberger.info/linux/2009/03/18/latex-using-apacite-and-hyperref-in-the-same-document/

Answer (score 7):

### Status in 2024

There are still loading order requirements, either because `hyperref` must overwrite a command or because other packages (like `cleveref`) wants to overwrite hyperref definitions.

But LaTeX offers now various tools (like the hook management) to avoid such loading order dances and they should not be viewed as inevitable fate but as something that can (and should) be repaired. For example amsmath already can also be loaded after hyperref.

### Report issues!

So if there is some issue: open an issue at the hyperref github, or ask here with a concrete example.

Answer (score 6):

- **`ocgx2`**

Besides providing commands for the creation and manipulation of PDF Layers (officially named **O**ptional **C**ontent **G**roups), this package re-implements **`hyperref`**'s **`ocgcolorlinks`** option.

> ```
> \usepackage{hyperref} % do NOT set [ocgcolorlinks] here!
> \usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}
> ```

This kind of coloured hyperlinks make use of PDF Layers in order to appear highlighted in the PDF viewer, but which are printed out on paper in the normal colour of the surrounding text, which is usually black.

As opposed to the original `hyperref` implementation, longer (ocg-)coloured links made with `ocgx2` are allowed to wrap around line endings and page breaks.

Answer (score 2):

It may be late answer (more a tip), but it cost me a lot to find out, so let me add a tip for other *Brazilian* users which for some documents must use the regional standard package `abntex2cite`.

`abntex2cite` must always be *after* `hyperref`. **If** `abntex2cite` is placed before `hyperref`, **then** the .bbl file will have errors and the references won't be properly written. The references are the main (*if not only*) reason to use `abntex2cite`.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Normas ABNT - Always after hyperref
```

Comment: `abntex2cite` is unsupported and deprecated for years. the way to go now is `biblatex-abnt`.

Comment: I agree `abntex2cite` is unsupported and old and so on. I've tested `biblatex` with `abnt` of my own, It works fine and is the way to go ... The **real** problem is I just don't know how to convence people like my advisor to use `biblatex` instead of `bibtex` AND at the same time correctly use the regional standard. Although he insists to use `natbib`, but `natbib` just doesn't write references and citations properly for all (many useless) cases. And in 2018 there was a huge update at the norms, which means more potential issues to deal.

Comment: as far as I know, `biblatex-abnt` does implement all `abnt` rules for references. `natbib` is just useless either with `abntex2cite` or with `biblatex`. The 2018 update wasn't that huge, either.

Comment: About the "hugeness". The 2002 version had 24 pages and the 201 version has 68. To my librarian it was "the hugest", but I've seen only some minor relevant changes (removing "< >" for urls is the main one in my opinion), but it takes some time to review all new examples.
On the other hand, there are still people coming to me asking about their thesis/dissertation that must be on LaTeX and they've always used Word and sometimes their templates use the even older `abnt.bst` etc. In this scenario, changing from `bibtex` to `biblatex` seems a "little too big" step for many people.

Comment: I doubt all those examples are really significant. Nobody cares, or if they care, they're really faking being advisors or committee members. At least with `biblatex` you can get in touch with people here on tex.stackexchange or even with the package writer himself if you need some extra functionality (besides all the extras `biblatex` provides already), whereas with `bibtex` you're basically stuck on your own. Anyway, good luck for ye all.

Comment: where is it said that abntex2cite has been deprecated in favor of biblatex-abnt?

Comment: @DanielDiniz, Read the section "*3 O novo pacote biblatex*" at [CTAN abntex2cite](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/doc/abntex2cite.pdf). You still may use `abntex2cite` and `abntex-alf.bst`, but you will need to edit them in order to achieve the standard given by [ABNT NBR 6023:2018](https://www.ufpe.br/documents/40070/1837975/ABNT+NBR+6023+2018+%281%29.pdf/3021f721-5be8-4e6d-951b-fa354dc490ed) and [ABNT NBR 10520:2002](http://www.uel.br/cef/def/portal/pages/arquivos/TCC/ABNT%20(NBR%2010520).pdf).

Comment: Read [this small summary](https://www.bu.cefetmg.br/2018/12/06/abnt-nbr-60232018-referencias-o-que-mudou/) to understand what have changed between versions. If you're gonna choose biblatex updated to the 2018 version, you're gonna need to download files from [GitHub biblatex](https://github.com/abntex/biblatex-abnt). If you're gonna keep `abntex2cite`, you may ask me for files and/or details of  implementation

Comment: hm, I see. well, in any case, AFAIK pretty much every brazilian college claims to follow ABNT but follows instead a weird mix of ABNT and arbitrary in-house rules. my school (IFCH/Unicamp) uses "rules" from the 90's... so it's a bit radical to say that abnt2cite has been deprecated, when its defaults still handle 90% of its users' needs

Comment: Strictly speaking, the "correct" use should be always following the newest version of each applied norm. Nevertheless, as I guess you read the abntex2cite section 4, there are very talented people in our universities (I'm also grad student from Unicamp) that just don't care or don't know about it. People will often follow the rules they have in their minds in opposition to check the actual standards. Our problem with both packages is that none of them are maintained anymore. Biblatex crew didn't update to CTAN the changes they did. Abntex stopped updating a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

If `hyperref` comes before `titlesec` it produces the warning "The anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not be the same" at `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` when using overleaf