# No room for a new \dimen when including TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No room for a new \dimen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen)

I have a fairly large document which uses 30 or so packages. I was going to add some TikZ graphics, so I added the following to my header file:

```
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
```

However, this gave me a lot of errors of the type

```
! No room for a new \dimen .
```

After looking around, this seems to be related to a limitation of TeX. Is it not possible to use TikZ with many other packages? I am using MikTeX 2.9 and pdflatex.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Write

```
\usepackage{etex}
```

just after the `\documentclass` line (it should be the first loaded package).

Comment: Excellent. I tried the `-enable-etex` switch but it didn't help.

Comment: @Ben. The `etex` package modifies how LaTeX allocates registers to use e-TeX. The command-line switch you added (which is on by default anyway) only makes the extensions available: it does not change how LaTeX actually works.

Comment: I had the same problem. When I put \usepackage{etex} after \usepackage{pgfplots} the errors remain. However, if I load etex before pgfplots it works fine and no more errors. Cheers!
Peter

Comment: That's most likely because `pgfplots` loads `tikz` internally and you need to ensure that the `etex` package is loaded before `tikz` is loaded, thus before `pgfplots` is loaded as well.

Comment: This worked also for a LyX (beamer) document. Instruction added first in the Preamble.