# Replacement for \unexpanded without eTeX extension

Tags: macros, expansion, e-tex

As comment on [Can the extended register pool be used for \newinsert?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40361/6865), there is a reference to [Dealing with tons of floats](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3049). It is interesting but uses `\unexpanded`:

```
\edef\@freelist{%
\unexpanded\expandafter{\@freelist\@elt}\expandafter\noexpand\ExtraFloatCommand}%
```

How can this be replaced by something like `\expandafter`, `\noexpand`, `\toks@`, which does not require the eTeX extension? (With eTeX probably `\etex@unexpanded` from the [`etexcmds` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etexcmds) would be better than `\unexpanded`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without the e-TeX extensions, you need to use a toks to have control of expansion inside an `\edef`. Usually, this is done using `\toks@`, and so to avoid any issues with other code a group is normally employed

```
\begingroup
  \toks@\expandafter{\@freelist\@elt}%
  \edef\@freelist{\the\toks@\expandafter\noexpand\ExtraFloatCommand}%
\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\def\expandafter\@freelist\expandafter{\@freelist}%
```

(You may be able to use `\xdef` here, but without a careful check I am not sure of the scope of `\@freelist`.)

You could also achieve the same directly using just `\expandafter`:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@freelist
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\@freelist\expandafter\@elt
  \ExtraFloatCommand}%
```

which works by first expanding `\ExtraFloatCommand`, then expanding `\@freelist`, both inside the new definition of `\@freelist`.

Comment: Both approaches are in my opinion much less readable than with e-TeX!

Comment: Yes, if one has e-TeX, it surely is to be preferred! +1 for the answer. While accepting after a short time might not be good style in general, I think your answer just provides THE "translation" (both ways of it, indeed!), therefore I just accept it now. Thank you!