# ! No room for a new \count . with showidx package

Tags: errors, indexing

I'm getting an error when I try to `\usepackage{showidx}`:

```
! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi
l.41 \newinsert\indexbox
```

The line number is from `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/showidx.sty`. This is a plain debian lenny install, with texlive 2007 :(

A minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage[backgroundcolor=yellow,textsize=scriptsize,textwidth=3.5cm]{todonotes}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Some text here \index{Blah}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

If I remove any of the other packages, the error goes away. Any idea what's causing this, and how I can get around it?

Comment: Note: I see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen, but I have tried adding `\usepackage{etex}`, and it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Use package `etex` and `\reserveinserts`, it is expained in the answer of [no-room-for-a-new-dimen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38609/16967).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: if I do that, I get `! Undefined control sequence.
l.3   \item \glossaryentry
                          {AOGCM?\glossaryentryfield{AOGCM}{\glsnamefont{AOG...`, which certainly wasn't happening before.

Comment: @naught101 This all works fine for me if I use the `etex` package and reserve 32 inserts. Try deleting any `.aux` file you have and running LaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As recommended in the commend by Heiko do the following:

1. Remove all help files generated by the LaTeX compilation
2. add `\usepackage{etex}` and `\reserveinserts`
3. compile again.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [FAQ-noroom](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-noroom.html)[1] works for me.

> It is essential that you load etex before any other packages, and reserve any extra inserts immediately:

```
\documentclass[...]{...}
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{28}
```

I add these two lines to my customized template file, which is loaded in `\documentclass[...]{customized-template}`, to ensure `etex` will be loaded before any other packages. And it compiling successfully.

[1] http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-noroom.html