# No room for a new \mathgroup

Tags: errors, memory

Using `MnSymbol`, `bm` and `pxfonts` together causes

> No room for a new \mathgroup

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38609/17049) to a similar question suggests using `etex`, but that doesn't help here. The `bm` documentation suggests inserting `\newcommand\hmmax{0}` to cut down on the number of fonts allocated, but again that doesn't help.

(Possibly relevant: I only need a few glyphs from each of `MnSymbol`, `pxfonts`, and a few `\bm` glyphs.)

Comment: Did you look at [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the `bm` package last (as documented:-) and it will all work out OK.

Comment: Thanks! But the documentation suggests this only matters for getting the best quality bold symbols (\S3.4), because it needs to query other packages. Why does loading it last reduce the resource requirements?

Comment: If bm thinks there are some spare mathgroups it will use them to more efficiently access the bold fonts. So they are not available for pxfonts. If you load pxfonts first bm knows how many spare slots it has to play with and works accordingly.