# bm and pxfonts conflict in beamer

Tags: beamer, bold

This is pretty much the same question as [No room for a new \mathgroup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86343/no-room-for-a-new-mathgroup), with the difference that the proposed solutions do not work when using the beamer class.

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{pxfonts}
 \usepackage{bm}  

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    $\frac{1}{2}$
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives a `no room for a new \mathgroup` error.

Is this solvable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: you're loading several useless math alphabets.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % don't bother loading the default fonts

\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
%\usepackage{pxfonts}
 \usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    $\frac{1}{2}$
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` seem preferable to `pxfonts`, if available (it is with an up-to-date TeX distribution).