# Conflict between TikZ with decorations.text library, caption and booktabs packages and progressbar theme

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pdftex, booktabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No room for a new \dimen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen)

I obtain an error when using simultaneously the above 4 elements. When removing one of them (which I do not wish), the output is fine.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}                 % 1
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} % 1
\usepackage{caption}              % 2
\usepackage{booktabs}             % 3
\usetheme{progressbar}            % 4

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The `progressbar` theme comes from [Sylvain Bouveret's webpage](http://recherche.noiraudes.net/fr/LaTeX.php).

The error message output by pdfLaTeX is the following (LaTeX does not return any error):

```
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                              \fi 
l.1253 \newdimen\MPscratchDim
                          % will be assigned global
?
```

Comment: It works if `XeLaTeX` or `TeX->PS->PDF` route is used with warnings about fadings of TikZ. So one of them is eating up the dimen registers in the PDF driver.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This seems to be a case already dealt with in [No room for a new `\dimen`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen). If this solves your issue, please tell us, so that this question can be closed; otherwise, tell why the suggested workaround does not apply.

Comment: Just after `\documentclass{beamer}`, add `\usepackage{etex}`.

Comment: Loading the etex package solves the issue, indeed. Thank you all. I am surprised that this minimal example saturates Pdftex.

Answer (score 10):

To use the extended pool for \dimen, you need to use the `etex` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz}                 % 1
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} % 1
\usepackage{caption}              % 2
\usepackage{booktabs}             % 3
\usetheme{progressbar}            % 4

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer solved a slightly different problem. Thanks anyway.