# Chemfig package compatibility

Tags: incompatibility, chemfig

Looking for help on the following problem:

I am trying to use `chemfig` package in my document, however after initial insertion had the following error:

```
!No room for a new \dimen.
```

I found [No room for a new \dimen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen) and added:

```
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{28}
```

but now I have another error:

```
!You can't use a prefix  with \begingroup
```

the answer to which I cannot seem to find online. Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Here is the minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublespacing,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{28}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{morehelp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{easytable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

\chemfig {*6(-=-(- M{(}OH{)}_2)=-=)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers and explanations! It worked great!

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be some problem with `chemfig` and `easytable`; loading `chemfig` *after* `easytable` solves the problem (I commented out the line loading the `morehelp` package, since my LaTeX system doesn't have it):

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublespacing,letterpaper]{report} 
\usepackage{etex} 
\usepackage{cite} 
%\usepackage{morehelp} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{easytable} 
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amstext} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\chemfig {*6(-=-(- M{(}OH{)}_2)=-=)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Solution

Reordering the load order will solve this issue: [Gonzalo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112707) demonstrates this nicely.

### Underlying cause

The underlying problem here is how the file `easy.sty` does its allocation of registers:

```
%
% define dimens for internal computation.
%
\@tempcnta=30\relax
\@whilenum\@tempcnta>\z@\do{%
   \expandafter\global\expandafter\newdimen\csname @easy@hsize\romannumeral\@tempcnta\endcsname%
   \expandafter\global\expandafter\newdimen\csname @easy@vsize\romannumeral\@tempcnta\endcsname%
   \advance\@tempcnta by\m@ne
}
```

This looks dense to the non-expert, but the key thing is that the `\newdimen` is being prefixed by `\global`. This is not necessary (dimensions are allocated globally by LaTeX), but is normally harmless.

The error arises if `\global\newdimen` occurs at the 'wrong' time. Classical TeX had only 256 dimens available, while e-TeX made many more (64k) accessible. However, the LaTeX `\newdimen` command is set up to only use the 256 classical ones, and so to actually use the 'extended pool' you have to alter part of the kernel. This is what the `etex` package does. However, it is set up to first use the 256 'standard pool' registers before altering how allocation is done for the 'extended pool'. That is all fine and usually is transparent. It goes wrong, however, if the switch happens when `\newdimen` is prefixed by `\global`, as the `\global` ends up 'in front' of an internal `\begingroup`, and that gives an error. (The error doesn't actually break the document, but no-one wants an error on every compile.)

Reordering loading will almost certainly skip the issue as it moves when the switch happens, hopefully away from the `\global\newdimen` use. A 'better' solution would be to alter `easy.sty` to not use `\global`, but as this file is 12 years old at time of writing I would not hold my breath on that. Perhaps the best solution would be to change `etex` to allow for an deal with the use of `\global` here: tricky and again a change in a file that has been unchanged for a long time.

Comment: I'm asking why `\global` is used there to begin with, because it ends in front of `\alloc@` that already begins with `\global`.

Comment: @egreg As I indicate in my answer, this is not required, and I'm not sure why people put a `\global` in (I came across this issue with some code Will Robertson wrote ages ago, and changed when it was pointed out it was not needed).

Comment: I just came across this error message in TeXLive 2013 due to a `\DeclareMathVersion` as the latex kernel used a `\global\newcount` in `\new@mathversion`. This problem has been resolved in TeXLive2014.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Glad to hear this :-)