# I am using the package ps-plot and a file that used to compile no longer compiles

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I am using the package `ps-plot` and a file that used to compile no longer compiles. The error I get says `No room for a new \dimen \ch@ck …\else \ermessage {No room for a new #3}\fi`

Please help! I need to give a talk and I can't get the file to compile.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Perhaps see [No room for a new `\dimen`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38607/5764)?

Answer (score 3):

Load

```
\usepackage{etex}
```

after your `documentclass`. If it doesn't help then you have probably a very old TeX distribution installed.