# xy and circuitikz conflict

Tags: beamer, xy-pic, circuitikz

Following MWE compiles:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Following MWE also compiles:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
%\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

But following doesn't compile:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

and gives [this error message](http://pastebin.com/DeEPekcV).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beamer is supposed to be a heavy class which loads many packages. This gives rise to the following error

```
No room for a n
ew \dimen 
(That was another \errmessage.)
```

This can be can be cured by `\usepackage{etex}` after `\documentclass{beamer}`. Please note that if you change the document class to `article` you don't get this error.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}      %%% New
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
   Me
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. A lot. Can you also explain what the error was and what is `etex`. Without guys like you I would really turn into a LaTeX hater.

Comment: @kamalbanga Thank you for the kind words. For an explanation, you may plaease refer to: [No room for a new \dimen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38609)