# What does the 'etex' package do, exactly?

Tags: packages, tex-core, e-tex, registers

I was creating a rather large `LaTeX` project, so I had to use many packages. This gave me an error

> `No room for a new \dimen \newdimen \MPscratchDim`

while my editor(Kile) opened the file `supp-pdf.mkii`, pointing at the line

> `\newdimen\MPscratchDim % will be assigned global`

Searching through the net, I found that this could happen due to loading too many packages, as answered in [No room for a new `\dimen`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen) by egreg.

Indeed I loaded, `etex` and everything works fine now. I searched `etex` on CTAN to understand what does this particular package do, but I am not able to understand what is going on. As stated by CTAN

> The pack­age pro­vides sup­port for LATEX doc­u­ments to use many of
>   the ex­ten­sions of­fered by e-TEX; in par­tic­u­lar, it **mod­i­fies**
>   LATEX’s **reg­is­ter al­lo­ca­tion** macros to make use of the **ex­tended
>   reg­is­ter range**

I believe that the bold words give the answer, but I cannot understand why there is a limited *register allocation* (I don't even know what that is) and how can a package *extend* this *register range*.

Any idea on that will be very educational!

Comment: If a register is defined by 8 bits, you can uniquely address 2^8=256 locations.  In the "old days" this may have been the norm.  As the hardware became capable, upgrading a register to 16 bits would extend your addressing range to 65536 locations.  (My first computer had 4096 total bytes of memory)

Comment: Originally, TeX provided a fixed amount of 256 different "dimension registers" (which is what is allocated by `\newdimen`). The code of the `\newdimen` macro reflects this by checking that not too many registers are allocated. The current eTeX engine extends this fixed number to 32768, but the code of `\newdimen` needs to be adapted to the new maximum number by the `etex` package.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

#### Update

Recent LaTeX kernels have incorporated the greater part of `etex`, so it's quite unlikely that one needs to load it nowadays.

---

#### Original answer

TeX, as designed by Knuth, has various registers addressable with an eight bit number (that is, from 0 to 255). Registers are of type

- `\count`
- `\dimen`
- `\skip`
- `\muskip`
- `\toks`
- `\insert`
- `\box`

Let's consider the `\dimen` registers, for the others the allocation mechanism is similar. Each register is addressable by its number, for instance

```
\dimen34=42pt
\kern\dimen34
```

are legal example of setting a `\dimen` register or retrieving its value. However, calling registers by number is a problem, because packages couldn't cooperate with each other. So all formats provide an *allocation* mechanism: one says

```
\newdimen\foo
```

and TeX sets up things so that `\foo` is the same as calling `\dimen<n>` where `<n>` represents a number that we *don't* need to know. Note that `\newdimen` is not a documented LaTeX command, but it is documented in `source2e` and is very useful when writing packages.

TeX/LaTeX keeps track of the most recent allocated number for each register type; since the maximum number is 255, when a `\newdimen` command hits the limit, the dreaded

```
No room for a new \dimen
```

error message appears. There is a slight complication because allocation of `\insert` registers starts from 254 down and each `\newinsert` also allocates the `\count`, `\dimen`, `\skip` and `\box` registers with the same number, so the upper limit is usually something less than 255, but it's not the main problem.

In case we hit the limit, there is nothing to do: we are forced to load less packages or do nasty tricks that will almost certainly bite us later on.

In order to solve this problem that became apparent several years ago when PicTeX was released, a different implementation of TeX was prepared that defines 32768 registers of each type. This is part of e-TeX, that is incorporated in `pdftex`, the engine used when we run LaTeX on a document.

However, the kernel of LaTeX has not been modified, because it's basically frozen apart from bug fixes. Changing the allocation mechanism might break documents or packages that have been written under the assumption that only 256 registers of each type are available.

The `etex` package modifies the allocation mechanism; when `\newdimen` would issue the `No room for a new \dimen` error message, it insteads jumps beyond 255 and allocates the register number 256 and goes forward from there.

Here is a simulation, where we assume that `\newdimen\foo` allocates the last available eight bit slot and `\newdimen\baz` needs to go up to fifteen bits; in the log file you'd find

```
\foo=\dimen233

Normal \dimen register pool exhausted, switching to extended pool.
\baz=\dimen256
```

provided you have `\usepackage{etex}` in your preamble.

Why 233 is the last? Because LaTeX allocates `\insert` classes from 254 to 234; they are connected with marginal notes, footnotes, figures and tables.

Answer (score 34):

classic TeX has 256 registers (eg count and dimen registers as allocated by `\newcounter` and `\newlength` in LaTeX.

For some years LaTeX formats have used the extended etex (or pdf(e)tex engines rather than classic TeX, so actually there are 32768 registers available. However for compatibility reasons (or stubbornness, or apathy, depending on your point of view) the default latex macros that allocate a name to a internal register number have not been updated so still only allow
numbers 0-255. So if you load etex package (or use lualatex and xelatex formats as currently constructed, which use similarly extended allocation) the macros are changed to use a different range.

Note that etex is active by default, you can use `\numexpr` or a count register such as `\count1000`, it is just that `\newcount` does not "know" that you may do that, so does not allocate any more than 255.

---

**UPDATE**

LaTeX releases from 2015 onwards do detect if they are running on etex (or xetex or luatex) and use the full extended register range by default.
Thus the `etex` package should not normally be used with new documents.

Comment: The format-building processes at present do not load `etex` even if they do other allocation-related things (all a bit strange).

Answer (score 14):

Run `texdoc etex` and you'll get the documentation of eTeX. Two of the nice new features are `\dimexpr` and `\numexpr`. Instead of 256 available counters, dimensions, etc. there are now 2^{15}.

> ε-TEX increases the number of TEX’s count, dimen, skip, muskip, box,
>   and token registers from 256 to 32768.

`eTeX` is the default engine for all programs except of the original TeX. To activate the `eTeX` extensions one has to include `\usepackage{etex}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! What I don't understand is what is a counter? For every package used, the counter increases by 1, which means that you can use only 256 packages? In addition what is a register? Or what is dimen, skip, muskip, box and token registers?

Comment: @Thanos latex commands such as `\newcounter` give counters for things like `equation` or `section` and the question is how many different such counters can you have. It is unrelated to package use.

Comment: All those facts are not important to the "normal" user, whatever this may be. A counter counts things like pages, equations, figures, tables, a.s.o.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I know that! That's why it's weird! My document has only a preamble with many packages and only a `hello world` within the `document` environment, so there's no need to "count" anything...

Comment: @Thanos: sure, but the documentclass and the loaded packages itself count a lot of things.

Comment: @Herbert : That's exactly what I didn't know! I didn't know that the loaded packages use a counter!

Comment: @Thanos A package *might* allocate one or more counters. It doesn't necessarily do.

Comment: @Thanos counters are allocated almost always at the start of the document so article class allocates counters figure, table, section, subsection, paragraph, subparagraph, so that these things could be counted, even if your document doesn't actually use any of those.