# pstricks-add incompatible with beamer?

Tags: beamer, pstricks

Beamer seems to clash with pstricks-add:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
 Lorem Ipsum
\end{document}
```

Gives the following error:

```
! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.1895 \newdimen\pst@chartHeight
```

But it runs smoothly without `pstricks-add` or replacing `beamer` with `article`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen

Comment: Indeed, loading etex solves the problem. Thank you.