# Option clash between TikZ, psplot, geometry, and hyperref

Tags: packages, incompatibility

I know someone who is working on a LaTeX document requiring pst-plot, geometry, and hyperref, and I recently gifted him some TikZ improvements of diagrams that didn't seem to be working out for him.

However, TikZ is clashing with the other packages, hyperref being the most critical. How does one circumnavigate around such an obstacle without sacrificing much?

**Edit**: Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[z,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
\usepackage{mathptmx,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

The error produced seems to be

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code
.tex:19: No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                   \fi 
l.19 \newdimen\tikz@lastxsaved
```

Comment: give a _small_ example which shows the option clash

Comment: In general, TiKZ, `geometry`, PSTrick and  `hyperref` coexist happily: we are going to need some form of examples to help here.

Comment: `\usepackage{etex}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Herbert pointed out in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195507/option-clash-between-tikz-psplot-geometry-and-hyperref#comment452458_195507), adding

```
\usepackage{etex}
```

directly after the line with `\documentclass` solves the problem. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38609/50960) explains why this works.