# LaTeX error with xy-pic

Tags: xy-pic

When i use the XY pack for LaTeX by adding the following line to my source:

```
\usepackage[all]{xy}
```

i get this error:

```
! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
\fi
l.192 \xynew@{dimen}\Y@min
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
\Y@min=\dimen234
```

I have still missing packages?

Comment: (1) Always post minimal example so we can see what you are doing. (2) try adding `\usepackage{etex}` to see if it helps.

Comment: an explanation of the `etex` solution (and why it works) is given in [No room for a new \dimen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38609/579)