# Are tickz and pstricks in conflict?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, pstricks

I do not know why, but it seem that the tikz and  pstriks packages are in conflict. Using both

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\uspepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
```

When compiling, it returns me the following error:

> !No room for a
>   new \dimen

I list below the packages that I used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[all,dvips,graph]{xy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
```

Note that without one of tikz or pstricks, it will compile.

Comment: Did you look at the answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen)?

Comment: @Thruston: yes and adding etex it works, but I want to understand why: I'm not using too many packages...

Comment: you don't need to use lots of packages, if you are using two of the biggest ones, and classic tex only has 256 dimen registers and latex uses up half of them before you start.

Comment: don't load epsfig! (it won't help this problem, but don't load it anyway)

Comment: Don't load `color` (TiKZ loads `xcolor`). Consider using `utf8` and UTF8 encoding.