# Unknown File Type on Math ArXiv

Tags: arxiv

I am not-quite-yet-minted Ph.D. in math, and I am attempting my first submission to the arXiv.

I uploaded all of my files except for one as a `.zip` file, and, when I realized I had which file I had forgotten, I uploaded it "manually" (that is, not as part of a `.zip` file), and it registered with the arXiv as and "unknown" file type, instead of as a file of type "TEX".

Now, no matter what I do, I can't get the arXiv to recognize the file as a "TEX" file. My document won't compile, and the error log I think is complete nonsense: the problem is that the arXiv's TeX complier isn't recognizing the `ch1sec3.tex` as a "TEX" file (as evidenced by the fact that it tries to typeset every file EXCEPT `ch1sec3.tex`).

TeX log appears below

```
[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <ch3sec1.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <ch2sec1.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <ch4sec2.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <ch1sec3-ihateyou.tex> is of type 'unknown'.
[verbose]: <ch4sec4.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <ch2sec2.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <dissertation.tex> is of type 'LATEX2e'.
[verbose]: <ch4sec1.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <dissertation.bbl> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <ch4sec3.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <ch1sec1.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <ch5sec1.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <ch5sec3.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <ch5sec2.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <ch4sec5.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: <ch1sec2.tex> is of type 'TEX'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'dissertation.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hlatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && latex 'dissertation.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./dissertation.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded
.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amscd.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/pictex.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/prepictex.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/pictex.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/postpictex.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/picmore.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/piccorr.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def))
! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
\fi
l.175 \newdimen\Gin@req@width

?
! Emergency stop.
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
\fi
l.175 \newdimen\Gin@req@width

No pages of output.
Transcript written on dissertation.log.

[verbose]: latex 'dissertation.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running latex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && latex 'dissertation.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./dissertation.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded
.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amscd.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/pictex.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/prepictex.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/pictex.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/postpictex.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/picmore.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/piccorr.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def))
! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
\fi
l.175 \newdimen\Gin@req@width

?
! Emergency stop.
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
\fi
l.175 \newdimen\Gin@req@width

No pages of output.
Transcript written on dissertation.log.

[verbose]: latex 'dissertation.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && pdflatex 'dissertation.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./dissertation.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
```

[...]

```
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
\fi
l.175 \newdimen\Gin@req@width

?
! Emergency stop.
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
\fi
l.175 \newdimen\Gin@req@width

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on dissertation.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'dissertation.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && pdflatex 'dissertation.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./dissertation.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded
.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amscd.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/pictex.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/prepictex.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/pictex.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/postpictex.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/picmore.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/piccorr.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
\fi
l.175 \newdimen\Gin@req@width

?
! Emergency stop.
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
\fi
l.175 \newdimen\Gin@req@width

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on dissertation.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'dissertation.tex' failed.
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'dissertation.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./dissertation.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on dissertation.log.

[verbose]: tex 'dissertation.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'dissertation.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./dissertation.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on dissertation.log.

[verbose]: tex 'dissertation.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'dissertation.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'ch1sec1.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch1sec1.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch1sec1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...$ induces an isomorphism $f_*:H_*(M;\mathbb
{Z}Q) \rightarrow H_*(M^+;...

?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 ...$ induces an isomorphism $f_*:H_*(M;\mathbb
{Z}Q) \rightarrow H_*(M^+;...

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch1sec1.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch1sec1.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch1sec1.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch1sec1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...$ induces an isomorphism $f_*:H_*(M;\mathbb
{Z}Q) \rightarrow H_*(M^+;...

?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 ...$ induces an isomorphism $f_*:H_*(M;\mathbb
{Z}Q) \rightarrow H_*(M^+;...

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch1sec1.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch1sec1.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'ch1sec1.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'ch1sec2.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch1sec2.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch1sec2.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \begin
{Theorem}[Existence of 1-sided s-cobordisms] \label{thmsemi-s-cob}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \begin
{Theorem}[Existence of 1-sided s-cobordisms] \label{thmsemi-s-cob}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch1sec2.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch1sec2.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch1sec2.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch1sec2.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \begin
{Theorem}[Existence of 1-sided s-cobordisms] \label{thmsemi-s-cob}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \begin
{Theorem}[Existence of 1-sided s-cobordisms] \label{thmsemi-s-cob}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch1sec2.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch1sec2.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'ch1sec2.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'ch2sec1.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch2sec1.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch2sec1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...nt work originally due to Quillen in \cite
{Quillen}. The manifold ve...

?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 ...nt work originally due to Quillen in \cite
{Quillen}. The manifold ve...

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch2sec1.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch2sec1.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch2sec1.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch2sec1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...nt work originally due to Quillen in \cite
{Quillen}. The manifold ve...

?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 ...nt work originally due to Quillen in \cite
{Quillen}. The manifold ve...

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch2sec1.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch2sec1.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'ch2sec1.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'ch2sec2.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch2sec2.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch2sec2.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...Group Extension Problem is based upon \cite
{MacLane} Chapter IV, sect...

?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 ...Group Extension Problem is based upon \cite
{MacLane} Chapter IV, sect...

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch2sec2.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch2sec2.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch2sec2.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch2sec2.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...Group Extension Problem is based upon \cite
{MacLane} Chapter IV, sect...

?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 ...Group Extension Problem is based upon \cite
{MacLane} Chapter IV, sect...

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch2sec2.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch2sec2.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'ch2sec2.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'ch3sec1.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch3sec1.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch3sec1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...to superperfect (defined in Definition \ref
{defsuperperfect} below), ...

?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 ...to superperfect (defined in Definition \ref
{defsuperperfect} below), ...

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch3sec1.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch3sec1.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch3sec1.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch3sec1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...to superperfect (defined in Definition \ref
{defsuperperfect} below), ...

?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 ...to superperfect (defined in Definition \ref
{defsuperperfect} below), ...

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch3sec1.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch3sec1.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'ch3sec1.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'ch4sec1.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch4sec1.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch4sec1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \indexspace

?
! Emergency stop.
l.3 \indexspace

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch4sec1.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch4sec1.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch4sec1.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch4sec1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \indexspace

?
! Emergency stop.
l.3 \indexspace

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch4sec1.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch4sec1.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'ch4sec1.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'ch4sec2.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch4sec2.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch4sec2.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \indexspace

?
! Emergency stop.
l.3 \indexspace

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch4sec2.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch4sec2.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch4sec2.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch4sec2.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \indexspace

?
! Emergency stop.
l.3 \indexspace

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch4sec2.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch4sec2.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'ch4sec2.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'ch4sec3.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch4sec3.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch4sec3.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...1}$. For $\omega \in \Omega$ and $n \in \BN
$, define $(\omega, n)$ to...

?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 ...1}$. For $\omega \in \Omega$ and $n \in \BN
$, define $(\omega, n)$ to...

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch4sec3.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch4sec3.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1184184/ && tex 'ch4sec3.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./ch4sec3.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...1}$. For $\omega \in \Omega$ and $n \in \BN
$, define $(\omega, n)$ to...

?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 ...1}$. For $\omega \in \Omega$ and $n \in \BN
$, define $(\omega, n)$ to...

No pages of output.
Transcript written on ch4sec3.log.

[verbose]: tex 'ch4sec3.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'ch4sec3.tex'
```

Comment: Perhaps read [No room for a new `\dimen`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38607/5764)... the same error appears in your `.log`.

Comment: you are using pictex (are you _really_ using pictex on a new document, I have not seen that used for 20 years:-) that uses a lot of dimen registers and you run out. You also get undefined `\mathbb` because `amsfonts` is not loaded. Does your document run without error locally?

Comment: In addition to the above comments, I suspect it unpacks the zip file in to a separate directory different from where your extra file is.  I'd delete all the uploaded files, create a new zip file and upload that.