# references to WinEdt guide template giving errors

Tags: bibliographies, biber

I am using the WinEdt QuickGuide.tex as a template to write a document, however, when I try to include the bibliography like:

```
%========================================================================================
%   Bibliography
%========================================================================================

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{C:/Superstar/Desktop/Joe/ModernControl/References/chap1.bib}% BibTeX
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
```

I get the error:

! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi

can you tell me how I can go about putting the references correctly in this template?

Comment: Does the info in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen help?

Comment: @JosephWright. thanks, that worked, but now I have a problem when I use the command: \printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book,prefixnumbers={B}]. I get the error \protect ...ing=bibempty,type=book...I've used this before in the book class, but is it because it is being used in the scrbook class?