# Sectioning bibliography by type of referred item

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, sorting, subdividing

My promoteur has a very unusual requirement: the bibliography needs to be sorted first by specific type of referred item, next by author and by year of publication.

I managed to get this custom sorting done by using `makebst` and manually editing the `.bst`, but now there is even greater problem for me: the bibliography itself must be sectioned, so it should look something like this:

---

### Sources

Aahn, A. 2008, whatever dude

Aahn, A. 2009, whatever dude, really

### Dictionaries

Encyclopeadia of everythinga, 1999

Wikipaedia, 2000-today

### Articles

Aahn, B. and Boss, C., 1889 This issue is not to our concern, good man

### Other Materia

Bactera, E.C., 1987, How we totally not-wiped the whole earth.

---

Can this be done automagically with `bibtex`? Or do I have to edit the generated file manually?

Comment: You could modify lockstep's excellent solution to this [similar problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited/6977#6977)...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There are several ways to have separate bibliographies by type of items cited.
I'll describe here some of them, namely:

- With `bibtex`

  - Using [**`splitbib`**](http://ctan.org/pkg/splitbib);
  - using [**`bibtopic`**](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic); and
  - using [**`multibib`**](http://ctan.org/pkg/multibib)
- With [**`biblatex`**](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)

## BibTeX

There are several, more or less complicated solutions to separate
bibliographies by type with `bibtex`, but that's not "automagicly" at all...

### Using `splitbib`

You can do that with the [**`splitbib`**](http://ctan.org/pkg/splitbib)
package, you have to define a bibliographic category and manually add the
corresponding itens to it, something like this:

```
\begin{category}[A]{First category}
\SBentries{entry1,entry4}
\end{category}
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{splitbib}
\begin{category}[A]{First category}
  \SBentries{article-minimal,article-full}
\end{category}
\begin{category}[B]{Second category}
  \SBentries{book-minimal,book-full}
\end{category}
\begin{document}
\cite{article-minimal,article-full,book-minimal,book-full}
\bibliography{xampl.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

> [image: splitbib example]

Check [splitbib documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/splitbib) for more details.

### Using `bibtopic`

As with `splitbib`, [`bibtopic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic) aims at other
possible usages besides separate bibliographies by type.

Since *it requires separate databases* for each bibliography section, it is more
indicated when you already them as such (i.e., separate `.bib` files for each
kind of item).

The usage is basically, e.g.:

```
\begin{btSect}{books}
\section{References from books}
\btPrintCited     % for cited references
\btPrintNotCited  % for references not cited
\end{btSect}
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibtopic}
\begin{filecontents}{books.bib}
@BOOK{book-minimal,
   author = {Donald E. Knuth},
   title = {Seminumerical Algorithms},
   publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
   year = {1981},
}
@BOOK{book-full,
   author = {Donald E. Knuth},
   title = {Seminumerical Algorithms},
   volume = 2,
   series = {The Art of Computer Programming},
   publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
   address = {Reading, Massachusetts},
   edition = {Second},
   month = {10~} # jan,
   year = {1981},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{articles.bib}
@ARTICLE{article-minimal,
   author = {L[eslie] A. Aamport},
   title = {The Gnats and Gnus Document Preparation System},
   journal = {\mbox{G-Animal's} Journal},
   year = 1986,
}
@ARTICLE{article-full,
   author = {L[eslie] A. Aamport},
   title = {The Gnats and Gnus Document Preparation System},
   journal = {\mbox{G-Animal's} Journal},
   year = 1986,
   volume = 41,
   number = 7,
   pages = {73+},
   month = jul,
   note = {This is a full ARTICLE entry},
}
@ARTICLE{article-notcited,
   author = {L[eslie] A. Aamport},
   title = {The Gnus and Gnats Document Preparation System},
   pages = "73+",
   journal = {\mbox{G-Animal's} Journal},
   year = 1987,
   volume = 42,
   number = 8,
   month = jul,
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\section{Testing}
Let’s cite all the books: \cite{book-minimal,book-full}; and articles:
\cite{article-minimal,article-full}.
\begin{btSect}{books}
\section{References from books}
\btPrintCited
\end{btSect}
\begin{btSect}[plain]{articles}
\section{References from articles}
\btPrintCited
\section{Articles not cited}
\btPrintNotCited
\end{btSect}
\end{document}
```

> [image: bibtopic example]

Notice that `bibtopic` requires a `bibtex` pass for each section, so you should
compile it with

```
latex <file>
bibtex <file>1
bibtex <file>2
...
bibtex <file>n
latex <file>
latex <file>
```

Check [`bibtopic` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/bibtopic) for more details.

### Using `multibib`

As with `splitbib`, and `bibtopic`, [`multibib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multibib)
aims at other possible usages besides separate bibliographies by type.

It does not require separate databases, but it creates a special citation
command for each type of item you define in the preamble.

The basic usage is to create a new citation type in the preamble with:

```
\newcites{mytype}{A Header for your special bibliographic type(s)}
```

And then cite the entries that should be considered in the new type with a
`\cite<newcites-arg>` command, e.g. `\citemytype`.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{book}{Books}
\begin{document}
\citebook{book-full,book-minimal}

\cite{article-minimal,article-full}
\bibliographystylebook{alpha}
\bibliographybook{xampl}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Other References}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

> [image: multibib example]

Notice that (as with `bibtopic`) it requires special `bibtex` passes:

```
latex <file>
bibtex <file>
bibtex <mytype>
latex <file>
latex <file>
```

Check [`multibib`documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/multibib) for more details.

## Using `biblatex`

You can do this quite "automagicly" with the [**`biblatex`**](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package! The usage is as simple as:

```
\printbibliography[type=book]
\printbibliography[type=collection]
\printbibliography[type=thesis]
```

or by adding a `keywords` field to your bib entry, and splitting it the bibliography with

```
\printbibliography[keyword=keyword1]
\printbibliography[keyword=keyword2]
```

or by creating categories like with the `splitbib` package, with something like

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{<category>}
\addtocategory{<category>}{<key>}
```

Here's a MWE using the first mentioned option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{xampl.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{article-minimal,article-full,book-minimal,book-full}
\printbibliography[type=article,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[type=book,title={Books}]
\end{document}
```

> [image: biblatex example]

Check [biblatex documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex) for more information.

To move to biblatex, I suggest you read the following questions:

- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701)
- [What to do to switch to biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091)
- [biblatex in a nutshell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)
- [What is the difference between bibtex and biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8411)

Comment: Thanks @henriqe, that was the spot on answer I was looking for. now I just have to style splitbib an it's done.

Comment: ok @johnny_bit, but i really suggest you consider using biblatex!

Comment: Are you sure this work? I'm using biblatex, added keywords = {keyword1} to my bib file, and then tired printing \printbibliography[keyword=keyword1]. Nothing happened, even after deleting auxiliary files and running everything again. I still got Keyword 'keyword1' not found on line.... error

Comment: @user19502 You can find a lot of sample documents for biblatex usage [online](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples) or on your computer already in the Tex tree at `texmf/doc/latex/biblatex/examples`. They should all work without any error messages; if you get error messages the problem is quite probably on your side.

Comment: @user19502, I'm pretty positive it works. Perhaps you've mispelled the entry field (a *very* common mistake I do), since the field is `keywords` and the command option `keyword`?