# Use custom tags to split bibliography

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

With `biblatex` you can split a bibliography based on keywords using

```
\printbibliography[keywords=mykeyword]
```

as documented in [Sectioning bibliography by type of referred item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20246/sectioning-bibliography-by-type-of-refered-item).

This seems to be hardwired to use the `keywords` field. Is there a way to divide the bibliography based on another field? Specifically, Mendeley inserts a `mendeley-tags` field that looks like:

```
mendeley-tags = {mytag1,mytag2,mytag3},
```

I have tried

```
\printbibliography[mendeley-tags=mytag3]
```

but that doesn't work.

Is there a way to set this up?

Comment: Have a look at [my edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/66318/revisions) of your question to see how [marking text as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) works. Bascially, you have to insert an empty line before the code block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With biblatex 2+ and biber 1+, you can do this in your preamble:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource=mendeley-tags, fieldtarget=keywords]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That gives me an error: ! Package keyval Error: fieldsource {mendeley-tags} undefined.

Comment: I had a feeling my method was dated. Looks like it is time to read the BibLaTeX and Biber manuals again.

Comment: It does work though, even if it gives an error! Thanks.

Comment: Try the editeed version - I don't think you need the braces I put in.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a dated answer as I have not really explored the potentially new data model in Biber 1.1.

If you create a new `.conf` file for `Biber` you should be able to map `mendeley-tags` to `keywords`

```xml
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_source="mendeley-tags" map_field_target="keywords"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks. Where would I put that .conf file so that biber see's it?

Comment: @user8786 you can put the file wherever you want (within reason) and then you point biber at the file with the -g option: biber -g /path/to/myconf/file/myconf.conf

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Your answer is still valid. PLK's answer just uses the new, convenient feature of specifying a source map in the document preamble instead of the configuration file.

Comment: Yes, in some ways this is better if you want this to always happen to any document - that's what the biber config file is for.