# Incorporating two styles of references

Tags: bibliographies, splitbib

In doing surveys and systematic literature reviews, we have ***References*** And ***Primary studies***: the studies that are being analyzed and reviewed in the review. Both needed to be referenced in the document.

Is there a way to have two separate reference styles in the latex file that differentiate between a reference and a primary study?
For example, we should have something similar to the following simple example:

```
In this review, we followed the procedures introduced in our earlier
work in [1] and [2] and extended by Heisenberg and Pinkman in [3] to analyse the
primary studies [PS1], [PS2], and [PS3].

References:
[1] Reference 1 
[2] Reference 2 
[3] Reference 3 

Primary studies:
[PS1] Primary Study 1
[PS2] Primary Study 2
[PS3] Primary Study 3
```

---

### Update: 01.02.2017

Based on the comments i tried the package `splitbib`.
I tried the same exact code provided in the [package documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/splitbib/splitbib.pdf), but I got the following error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \@bibitem.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> test.tex
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

when i run the script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{splitbib}
\begin{category}[A]{First category}
\SBentries{entry1,entry4}
\end{category}
\begin{category}[B]{Second category}
\begin{category}{First sub-category}
\SBentries{entry2,entry6}
\end{category}
\begin{category}{Second sub-category}
\SBentries{entry5,entry3}
\end{category}
\end{category}
\begin{document}
We cite~\cite{entry1,entry3,entry4,entry5}. Note that we cite neither
\verb+entry2+ nor \verb+entry6+,even though they have been assigned a category. defined in the last category. The first
sub-category will then not appear in the bibliography.
% \def\SBlongestlabel{A1}
\SBtitlestyle{bar}
\SBsubtitlestyle{none}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{entry1} This is the first entry.
\bibitem{entry3} This is the third entry.
\bibitem{entry4} This is the fourth one.
\bibitem{entry5} This is the last one.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look at <a href="https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib?lang=en">multibib</a>

Comment: @marmot, that package does not give control over the labels, i.e, I cannot provide the indexing style. It is restricted to the classical reference styles.

Comment: If you are willing to switch to BibLaTeX, this would be absolutely no problem there. At least the separation in two bibliographies. I am sure the separate label style can also be realized somehow.

Comment: @M.M. Sorry, I disagree. I achieved precisely what is desired, and was using my own bibstyles. (It is true that some very old TeXLive distributions caused problems, but with the more recent ones everything was smooth.)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20246/15925