# BibLaTeX: generate which reference types you have in your .bib file for automatically generating bibliography headings

Tags: biblatex

I could write a simple program for this in a programming language I know (or just terminal, I suppose), but is there a simple way to do this in LaTeX?

Maybe this could be done in LuaLaTeX? The regex to get the reference types is just `@.*\{` (at least in Sublime Text).

I have entries like `@online` and `@article` but I don't know which ones I have and which ones I don't and my bibliography file is pretty big. I want to make a reference list that is sorted per type, but in order to do that I need to know what article types I have first!

I found a way to do it in Sublime (copy/paste bib file in Sublime --> select all with the regex `@.*\{` --> alt + enter --> go to edit --> permute lines --> unique), but I am still leaving the question open for a (Lua)LaTeX style answer.

Now I can do it as stated in [Sectioning bibliography by type of referred item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20246/sectioning-bibliography-by-type-of-referred-item)

I currently have to type:

```
\printbibliography[type=article,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,title={Conference papers}]
\printbibliography[type=book,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[type=inbook,title={Book Chapters}]
\printbibliography[type=incollection,title={Chapters in a Collection}]
\printbibliography[type=MastersThesis,title={Master Theses}]
\printbibliography[type=techreport,title={Tech Reports}]
\printbibliography[type=misc,title={Misc}]
```

Which is fine but I am still wondering how one can do it more automatically.

Comment: Ideally you don't need to know that and everything happens automatically. Do you want a split bibliography with different subheadings, or just really only sorting by type?

Comment: I want to sort by type and perhaps give a semi-generalized name to it. And I know that I don't need to it ideally but when I look at the BibLaTeX tutorials on how to divide everything up in sub-headings it seems pretty manual. For example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20246/sectioning-bibliography-by-type-of-referred-item

Comment: I suppose a sourcemap and a `bibbycategory` could automate things somewhat.

Comment: But another alternative would be to devise a way to check you your current `\printbibliography` statements are exhaustive. A hook and a `alreadyinbib` category should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you originally asked for. It generates a list of entry types used

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand*{\usedbiblatextypes}{}
\AtDataInput{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{entrytype}}{\usedbiblatextypes}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\usedbiblatextypes}{\thefield{entrytype}}}}

\newcommand*{\printallentrytypes}{%
  \ifdefvoid{\usedbiblatextypes}
    {}
    {You used the following entry types:
     \begin{itemize}
     \forlistloop{\item}{\usedbiblatextypes}%
     \end{itemize}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}
\printbibliography

\printallentrytypes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! This is indeed what I originally asked for. I wonder what a good resource is to start LaTeX programming. I understand half of it. I have never programmed in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a simpler approach than you had initially imagined. I understand you'd like to have your bibliography split among the entrytypes, but are looking for a safe way to "not leave anything out".

The below provides an easy way to check whether you have left something out or not. Essentially, you can create a category `alreadyinbib` and add a `AtEverybibitem` hook to add any referenced entry to that category. With this, you can catch any remaining entries with a `\printbibliography[notcategory=alreadyinbib]`. If there are any entries in there, find what their entrytypes are, add them to your list, until the `alreadyinbib` bibliography results empty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{alreadyinbib}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \addtocategory{alreadyinbib}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[type=article,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,title={Conference papers}]
\printbibliography[type=book,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[type=inbook,title={Book Chapters}]
\printbibliography[type=incollection,title={Chapters in a Collection}]
\printbibliography[type=MastersThesis,title={Master Theses}]
\printbibliography[type=techreport,title={Tech Reports}]
\printbibliography[type=misc,title={Misc}]
\printbibliography[notcategory=alreadyinbib,title={Missing Entrytypes}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good approach. I did frame the question a bit too implementation specific originally.

Comment: Indeed, there is a tinge of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) in your question, in my view. That's why I thought it would be worth to suggest you another approach.