# Bibliography and sitography

Tags: bibliographies, tufte

I'm creating my thesis in LaTeX and it's the first time I use it. As a template I'm using that of Tufte.

I have a bibliography and I would also like to create a sitography separate from the bibliography (on another page).

This is a piece of my code:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \cite{ColinWare_InformationVisualization}, \cite{BenShneiderman_TheEyesHaveIt}, \cite{UsabilityFirst}.

\backmatter
\bibliography{./bib/bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

and `bibliography.bib` is:

```
@book{ColinWare_InformationVisualization,
    author = {Colin Ware},
    title = {Information visualization: perception for design},
    year = {2012},
    publisher = {Morgan Kaufmann},
    edition = {Third},
    isbn = {978-0123814647}
}

@report{BenShneiderman_TheEyesHaveIt,
    author = {Ben Shneiderman},
    title = {The eyes have it: a task by data type taxonomy for information visualizations},
    year = {1996}
}

@misc{UsabilityFirst,
    title = {{Usability first} Scientifi visualization definition},
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.usabilityfirst.com/glossary/scientific-visualization/}}
}
```

I want to separate `misc` elements to `report` and `book` elements. 
`report` and `book` elements should be in a section called Bibliography, `misc` elements should be in a section called Sitography.

---

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, defernumbers]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\backmatter
%\bibliography{./bibliografia/bibliography}
%\bibliography{./bibliografia/sitography}
\printbibliography[nottype=online, heading=subbibliography, title=Bibliography]
\printbibliography[type=online, heading=subbibliography, title=Sitography]
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

Errors:

[image]

---

We are almost there. Here's what I got:

[image]

Why in brackets there are no numbers but the letter `o`?
Why is the title not formatted as if it were the title of a chapter?

Thene elements of type booklet, misc and online are not printed..

```
@misc{GleamArt,
    ALTauthor = {Wouter Van den Broeck, Corrado Gioannini, Bruno Gonçalves, Marco Quaggiotto, Vittoria Colizza, Alessandro Vespignani},
    title = {The GLEAMviz computational tool, a publicly available software to explore realistic epidemic spreading scenarios at the global scale},
    date = {2011},
    OPTurl = {https://bmcinfectdis.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2334-11-37}
}
@online{UsabilityFirst,
    ALTauthor = {},
    title = {Usability first: scientific visualization definition},
    date = {2011},
    url = {http://www.usabilityfirst.com/glossary/scientific-visualization/}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is a sitography? You'll need to load additional packages for split bibliographies or you could switch your entire bibliography to `biblatex`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20246/35864 for a survey of the different options you have.

Comment: maybe `multibib` could help, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/oAtOpHsPF1w

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the link. I want to try the last method but I don't know how to modify my file. Can you help me more?

Comment: Can you show us a more minimal example of your code, please? Read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864 thoroughly. Then edit your code example to throw out stuff that is not relevant (`listings` and its definitions, the colour definitions) and we don't have (your `\include` files) and include a few example `.bib` entries and citations.

Comment: @moewe I edit my main message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `biblatex` you could try something like this.

Note that the `filecontents` bit is only to make the example self-contained. In your real document you will have a normal `.bib` file.

The `tufte-book` class normally loads `natbib`, so we explicitly tell it that we want to take over full control over which package we load by passing the `nobib` option to the document class. (You get errors if you don't do that since `natbib` and `biblatex` are incompatible.)

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, defernumbers]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ColinWare_InformationVisualization,
  author    = {Colin Ware},
  title     = {Information visualization: perception for design},
  year      = {2012},
  publisher = {Morgan Kaufmann},
  edition   = {3},
  isbn      = {978-0123814647}
}
@report{BenShneiderman_TheEyesHaveIt,
  author = {Ben Shneiderman},
  title  = {The eyes have it: a task by data type taxonomy for information visualizations},
  year   = {1996}
}
@online{UsabilityFirst,
  title = {{Usability first} Scientific visualization definition},
  url   = {http://www.usabilityfirst.com/glossary/scientific-visualization/},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \cite{ColinWare_InformationVisualization,BenShneiderman_TheEyesHaveIt,UsabilityFirst}.

\backmatter
\printbibliography[nottype=online, heading=subbibliography, title=Bibliography]
\printbibliography[type=online, heading=subbibliography, title=Sitography]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I made the online source an `@online` entry, but you can do the same thing with `@misc` if you prefer that.

Note that you will have to run Biber instead of BibTeX, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864), and that in general you are now using `biblatex` and not `natbib` any more, so you might want to read [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864).

Comment: Thank you so much but I can not compile the file.
I modified my file adding `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, defernumbers]{biblatex}`, I removed `\bibliography{./bibliografia/bibliography}` and added `\printbibliography[nottype=online, heading=subbibliography, title=Bibliography]`, `\printbibliography[type=online, heading=subbibliography, title=Sitography]` (see the modified code in the main message).
Then on TeXstudio I chose Bibliography --> type: BibTeX.
Compiling I get some errors.

Comment: @jennifer You need to add the option `nobib` to your document class. And you also need to configure your system for Biber see the last two links in my answer.

Comment: @jennifer Additionally you should also remove the `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` and you should delete the temporary `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.blg` files in your working directory.

Comment: Ok, one last thing: how do I insert the path of the files for the bibliography and the sitography? I removed the code related to the `filecontents`, and I have the two files `bibliography.bib` and `sitography.bib` but I do not know how to include them.
In fact now, thanks to your advice, the code compiles but does not appear neither the bibliography nor the sitography.

Comment: @jennifer I have added another link to my answer that explains this in more detail. Basically you just need `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}` and `\addbibresource{sitography.bib}` where my example has the `filecontents` stuff and `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}`.

Comment: I changed the main message again. The bibliography works but there are some formatting problems..

Comment: @jennifer I explicitly changed the headings to `\section`, but you can revert that by deleting the `heading=subbibliography`. The zeros could be caused by not running LaTeX often enough. You will at least have to run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX.

Comment: Actually, thank you for your patience, you are very kind. And what about the `@misc`, `@online`  elements that are not printed?

Comment: @jennifer Mhhh, they should be printed (at least the `@online` source, the `@misc` would appear in the bibliography, not the sitography). Delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and compile again with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX. Then show the output and the `.blg` and `.log` files if something is still going wrong.