# usign documentclass extarticle How to format bibliography titles as section, subsection

Tags: bibliographies

How can I format the titles "**Books**" and "**Thesis**" to appear as `\subsections`?

I think there are packages like **multibib**, but it does not work with **`reference.bib`**
I want to divide the bibliography with the following rule:

**Books**

they will go all the appointments that have to do with books.

```
@BOOK{}
```

**Thesis**
Here are going all the appointments that have to do with articles

```
@article{}
```

ok mi text document

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\section{Hi Group}
\subsection{Hi}
\subsubsection{I only}
\begin{quote}
 reference article ~\cite{2018_tailand}, other book ~\cite{fred_invs}.
\end{quote}
\section{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
%-----add action------
\section{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{referency}  %---reference ---
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\end{document}
```

in **referency**.bib

```
@article{2018_tailand,
author = {Jaichuen, Nongnuch and Chaiyasong},
year = {2018},
month = {06},
pages = {},
title = {ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION AMONG THAI UNIVERSITY STUDENTS},
volume = {sport participation}

@article{usa_2012,
title = "Alcohol use among college students",
author = "Mette Gilla",
year = "2012"
}

@BOOK{fred_invs,
author = "FRED N. KERLINGER; HOWARD B. LEE",
title = "Alcoholism from a gender perspective",
journal = "Spanish Journal of Drug Addiction",
volume = "4ed",
journal = "McGraw-Hill",
year = "2002"
}
```

**I need the result to be like the image below**

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Your question isn't very clear as you don't have the titles you mention anywhere I can see. Are you asking how to split the bibliography according to some rule? If so, what rule? You cite articles and books, so where do articles go and where does the thesis come from? Also, you've tagged this `biblatex`, but you aren't using Biblatex. Is Biblatex/Biber an option? If so, that's important to know as it is much easier to split bibliographies with that combination.

Comment: edited, now is understood ?, please I need help

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20247/87678 help?

Comment: Your code shows that you are not using `biblatex`, so I have removed the tag for now. If you are open for a `biblatex` solution, which would require more changes to your document and build set-up (you would not be able to use `alpha.bst`, but you could find a similar style), please mention that explicitly. Just to be sure: The picture in the end is what you would like to see from your code, right?

Comment: yes, but usign multibib

Comment: Does the linked question work for you? Several approaches are demonstrated there.