# Problem in splitting Sitography and Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am new at this site so first of all sorry if my question could be trivial.

I need to split for my dissertation the Sitography and the Bibliography (I have realized the bibliography with `biblatex`, so creating separated files `Bibliography.bib` and `Sitography.bib` with respect to the `main.tex`)

Moreover in the main I have:

```
\begin{document}    
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\markboth{Bibliography}{}   


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Sitography}
\markboth{Sitography}{}
 \end{document}
```

When I compile and execute the code, the result is given by two copies of the bibliography...I don't know how show the sitography...can you help me?

Comment: The code you have shown so far suggests you are using classical BibTeX and not `biblatex`, so I retagged the question. With classical BibTeX you need additional packages to split the bibliography, e.g. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic. A nice overview over available solutions can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20246/35864

Comment: Thanks for the correction...so simply creating two files .bib does not guarantee that sitography and bibliography will be separated?

Comment: That is correct. Additional work is needed to tell BibTeX to separate bibliography lists. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20246/35864 has examples for all packages that I know of that could help you here.