# How to create a second bibliography?

Tags: multibib

I want to have two separate bibliographies, one is for Internet sources, the other is for books.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{sec}{Internetquellen}


\begin{document}

Text......


Hallo \cite{3}   Hallo \citesec{A} 


%1.Literaturverzecihnis
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Literatur}

%2.Literaturverzecihnis
\bibliographystylesec{plain}
\bibliographysec{AndereLiteratur}

\end{document}
```

Somehow, LaTeX doesn't recognize `\bibliographysec`. Does TeXMaker needs to be setup in a specific way for this to work?

The sources are saved inside the `.bib` files, of course.

Comment: Welcome! This site is English only, could you translate your question please --- Willkommen! Diese Seite ist nur Englisch, könnten Sie Ihre Frage bitte übersetzen

Comment: Vielleicht versuchst du dein Glück eher auf [TeXwelt.de](https://texwelt.de/). This one is a strictly English site.

Comment: If you only just want to split up your list of references, you could still use one single bib file and then apply something like `\printbibliography[title=Internet sources, type=online]` or `\printbibliography[title=Other references, nottype=online]` or `\printbibliography[title=..., keyword=...]`, which would ony print those entries from the bib file that match the relevant `type` or `keyword`.

Comment: No additional work is needed for LaTeX to recognise the command `\bibliographysec`. It is possible that your editor (or rather your editor's code highlighting heuristic) does not recognise it, but this is not a real LaTeX issue unless the LaTeX run itself produces an error message about that. (Many editors have a heuristic to analyse code and help you with additional hints and warnings. Usually these heuristics "are not TeX" and sometimes they can get stuff wrong.) ...

Comment: ... A document with multiple bibliographies generated by `multibib` does need some special treatment, though. It is not enough to run the usual LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX compilation cycle on the file (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for more details). BibTeX needs to be run on additional files. If your editor usually does the compilation steps for you, you may have to run these steps manually. (Good compile tools like `latexmk` can automatically run the required BibTeX calls, but your editor might not.)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20246/35864 shows several ways of generating split bibliographies. The answer assumes some familiarity with compiling TeX files from the terminal (which you need for `multibib` and friends).