# Difference between bibliography management styles

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, compiling, best-practices

There are two ways that I've seen people including their bibliographies. The first is without including any package:

```
% Document:
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{<file>}
```

And the second includes `biblatex`:

```
% Preamble:
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{<file>.bib}
% Document:
\printbibliography
```

What exactly is the difference between these, and which is preferred in what situation?

Comment: Does it help: [What is the difference between bibtex and biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/what-is-the-difference-between-bibtex-and-biblatex)

Answer (score 4):

`\addbibresource` is a `biblatex`-only command. The main (only?) difference to the traditional `\bibliography` command is that `biblatex/biber` do not exclusively work with `.bib` files but allow for other bibliographic formats. That also explains why `\addbibresource` insists on the file suffix.