# modify bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Hi I want to modify biliographystyle unsrt, this style return :

Einstein journal paper [1].

But I want :

Einstein journal paper (Einstein 1905, [1]).

With the same entry in the bibliography section. I have test citep but it doesn't work, and I have chose other biliographystyle but I prefer the unsrt bibliographystyle.

example.tex source :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\begin{document}
Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}.
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

example.bib source :

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This style calls for `biblatex`, which is a very extendable alternative to `bibtex`.  See [What is the difference between bibtex and biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8411) and [biblatex in a nutshell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509) for a bit more information.

You can load `biblatex` with

```
% Load BibLaTeX
\usepackage[
        backend=bibtex, % You can still use bibtex, but it is also worth checking out biber
        citestyle=authoryear,
        ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname} % or bibliography[.bib] - no extension
```

Note, with `backend=bibtex`, you will still use the `latex > bibtex > latex > latex` compilation dance. But you should also check out `biber`, which is an alternative backend that allows for even fancier things with the bibliography.  (See also [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib/25702#25702)).

After a few customizations, you have the format that you desire as the default.  Play around with the settings to see if it will work for you.

### Working Example

[image: bibliography]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % Removed, not used in biblatex

% Load BibLaTeX
\usepackage[
        backend=bibtex, % You can still use bibtex, but it is also worth checking out biber
        citestyle=authoryear,
        ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname} % or bibliography[.bib] - no extension



% Make \cites \parencite by default
\let\cite\parencite

% Make bibmacro to create the key (doesn't exist with authoryear by default)
\newbibmacro*{cite:key}{%
  \printtext[brackets]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}

% Renew cite style for format you desire
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \printtext{\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:key}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}


\begin{document}
Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}.
\printbibliography % \bibliography becomes \printbibliography
\end{document}
```