# Why doesn't Pandoc convert citations correctly from Markdown to LaTeX?

Tags: citing, tools, pandoc, markdown

Consider the following markdown fragment:

```
Connecting these native implementations to the Python world is enabled
by the [Cython](http://cython.org/) toolchain  [@behnel2011cython].
```

I use pandoc to convert from markdown to LaTeX:

```
pandoc --chapters ../Source/Chapters/Content.md -o ../Example/Chapters/Content.tex
```

This is converted to LaTeX and produces the following output:

```
Connecting these native implementations to the Python world is enabled
by the \href{http://cython.org/}{Cython} toolchain~
{[}@behnel2011cython{]}.
```

Why is the citation not handled appropriately? It should be easy to simply convert it to `~\cite{behnel2011cython}`. Did I forget to give pandoc some flag for this?

Comment: I don't use `pandoc` for this kind of conversion, so apologies if I'm way off, but I thought you needed to use the `pandoc-citeproc` filter..?

Comment: @jon If I just add the filter this does not give me the desired output. Maybe I'm misunderstanding `pandoc-citeproc`.

Comment: Maybe.  What is the desired output?  I think the default is something like (biblatex) authordate.  But that is only one of many possible bibliographical outputs, and may not be what you are looking for.  I don't know how MWEs should look for a markdown-to-LaTeX document, but your original question does not give any indication about what 'style' you need.  And bibliographies are, fundamentally, idiosyncratic to say the least....

Comment: @jon My desired output is described above. It is simple text replacement. Pandoc does not need to look at a bibtex file to produce it.

Comment: Ah, well, like I said, I don' use `pandoc` in this way.  But you are wrong, I think, about the need to look at a BibTeX file.  This works: `pandoc infile.md --biblatex --biblio bibfile.bib -o outfile.tex` (or use `--natbib` instead of `--biblatex`).  This probably makes sense, too: the are lots of files `pandoc` might convert which do *not* have an associated bibliograpy, so it is better to need to turn on this behaviour. FYI: This does not provide the unbreakable `~` before the `\cite`, although maybe it would if you used the right CSL style.

Comment: @jon I got this to work using `--natbib --biblio <bibfile>`, thank you.

Comment: @jon It seems that your comments should be an answer

Answer (score 17):

If you want to use citations, you also have to define the CSL-style (*Citation Style Language*) to be used, via a *`*.csl`*-file you have to reference.

Here is an MWE in Markdown. It tests a few different methods to provide references to citations in Markdown:

````
# Markdown source code for relevant part of this page

``` {.markdown}
i.  [@nonexistent]
i.  @nonexistent
i.  @z1 says fooo.
i.  @z1 [p. 30] says baaar.
i.  @z1 [p. 30, with suffix] says blahblah.
i.  @z1 [-@z2 p. 30; see also @z3] says blah-blubb.
i.  In a footnote.[^1]
i.  A citation group [see  @z1 p. 34-35; also @z3 chap. 3].
i.  Another one [see @z1 p. 34-35].
i.  And still another, in a footnote.[^2]
i.  Quote with a *suffix* and a *locator* [@z1 pp. 33, 35-37, and nothing else].
i.  Quote with only one locator [@z1 and nowhere else].
i.  Now a few *modifiers*[^3]...
i.  With some extra Markup [*siehe* @z1 p. **32**].
i.  Jane Doz doesnt like me [***siehe*** **@z4**].

[^1]: A citation without locators [@z3].

[^2]: Multiple citations [siehe @z2 chap. 3; @z3; @z1].

[^3]: ...like a quote without author: [-@z1]. And now OStR Oster with a locator [-@z2 p. 44].

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$ @z1
```

# Document output of Markdown code

i.  [@nonexistent]
i.  @nonexistent
i.  @z1 says fooo.
i.  @z1 [p. 30] says baaar.
i.  @z1 [p. 30, with suffix] says blahblah.
i.  @z1 [-@z2 p. 30; see also @z3] says blah-blubb.
i.  In a footnote.[^1]
i.  A citation group [see  @z1 p. 34-35; also @z3 chap. 3].
i.  Another one [see @z1 p. 34-35].
i.  And still anoter, in a footnote.[^2]
i.  Quote with a *suffix* and a *locator* [@z1 pp. 33, 35-37, and nothing else].
i.  Quote with only one locator [@z1 and nowhere else].
i.  Now a few *modifiers*[^3]...
i.  With some extra Markup [*see also* @z1 p. **32**].
i.  Jane Doz doesnt like me [***see*** **@z4**].

[^1]: A citation without locators [@z3].

[^2]: Multiple citations [siehe @z2 chap. 3; @z3; @z1].

[^3]: ...like a quote without author: [-@z1]. And now OStR Oster with a locator [-@z2 p. 44].

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$ @z1

# Bibliography
````

You convert this Markdown with f.e. the following Pandoc command:

```
pandoc -V geometry="paperwidth=18cm, paperheight=34cm, margin=0.3cm" \
       -V language=de-DE -V lang=ngerman                             \
       --highlight-style=espresso --filter=pandoc-citeproc           \
       --biblio=my-biblio.bib --csl=stuttgart-media-university.csl   \
       -o stuttgart-media-university---csl.pdf mwe.md
```

As you can see from the command, it references three files:

1. The Markdown source, **`mwe.md`**.
2. An additional file defining the CSL-style to be used, **`stuttgart-media-university.csl`**. (I downloaded it from the core repository, of [citationstyles.org](http://citationstyles.org) on **[GitHub](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles.git)**.)
3. The third one, **`my-biblio.bib`**, which holds my citation references. Its content is here:

   ```
   @Book{z1,
   author="Thales von Milet",
   title="Doppelwinkel-Funktionen",
   url="http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Trigonometrie#Doppelwinkelfunktionen",
   year="600 v.Chr.",
   address="Milet, Kleinasien",
   publisher="Wikipedia"
   }

   @Article{z2,
   author="OStR Dr. math.nat. Oster",
   title="Unterrichtsmaterialen für Klasse 9 (Mittelstufe)",
   year="1969",
   journal="Journal of Generic Studies",
   volume="9",
   pages="33-34"
   }

   @InCollection{z3,
   author="Elvis Presley, Madonna and Pink Floyd",
   title="Kombinatorik Hypergeometrischer Verteilungen",
   booktitle="Wiederholungslose Auswahlprobleme",
   editor="Cleopatra, Königin von Ägypten",
   publisher="Steintafeln Moses GmbH & Co. KG",
   address="Gizeh",
   year="30 v.Chr."
   }

   @Article{z4,
   author="Jane Doz",
   title="Why All Men Suck",
   year="2006",
   journal="Journal of Gender Studies",
   volume="6",
   pages="33-34"
   }
   ```

Here is a screenshot of the resulting PDF page:

[image: Screenshot of resulting PDF, "stuttgart-media-university---csl.pdf"]

Looking closely at that page, you can see how exactly each occurrence of Markdown source citational references translate into the final page layout.

***Be aware, that the final page layout is heavily influenced by the specific CSL style file you use!*** Apply a different CSL, and the page content will look different (specifically: the spots with the references, the footnotes and the "Bibliography" section are all influenced by the CSL).

> *My recently created **[GitHub repo for testing CSL style files](https://github.com/KurtPfeifle/pandoc-csl-testing)** contains even more detailed instructions about this topic.*

Comment: Does this work with the `--biblatex` or `--natbib` options?

Comment: "If you want to use citations, you also have to define the CSL-style" I don't think this is completely true. You have to use the `pandoc-citeproc` filter which uses a default CSL file. Defining a CSL file is optional. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @KhalidHussain: You may be right... however I cannot tell from the top of my head. It should be easy to verify: just use the command I've given, and skip the `--csl=...` parameter altogether. If it works without an error printed out, and if the result shows citations, then you'll see a/the default CSL style it used.

Comment: "By default, `pandoc-citeproc` will use the Chicago Manual of Style author-date format." – [Pandoc Manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations)

Comment: This answer will produce formatted citations in the output document, but the OP wants to convert markdown citation _commands_ to latex citation _commands_. That simply requires adding `--biblatex` or `--natbib` options, which will convert the markdown citation commands to the corresponding latex commands. Even at that, the solution for outputting formatted citations is merely to invoke the `--filter=pandoc-citeproc` option (in older pandoc versions) or simply `--citeproc` in current versions.

Comment: @Scard: Thank you for your comment. But you are 6 years too late. Back in 2015 the options you gave didn't work.

Answer (score 13):

Just use the flag `--biblatex` when converting with `pandoc`:

```
pandoc --biblatex --chapters ../Source/Chapters/Content.md -o ../Example/Chapters/Content.tex
```

The result:

```
Connecting these native implementations to the Python world is enabled
by the \href{http://cython.org/}{Cython} toolchain
\autocite{behnel2011cython}.
```

You have to use the [`biblatex` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) for this to work -- but you really should use it anyway, because it's pretty fantastic: [The documentation](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) is excellent, and the package itself is very 'mature'. Here are some relevant questions to get you started:

- [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots)
- [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)
- [What is the difference between bibtex and biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/what-is-the-difference-between-bibtex-and-biblatex)

Comment: Will this work with markdown-style references? (like `[-@myref]`)? Or do I have to use `autocite`?

Comment: For some reason, this has to be at the *command-line* (doesn't work in the Yaml header).

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to `--biblatex` you can use `--natbib` so that LaTeX package 'natbib' commands (e.g. `\citep` and `\citet`) are used.