# pandoc/markdown: make citations compile to \cite instead of \autocite

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, pandoc, markdown, pandoc-citeproc

I am using a custom R Markdown Latex Template, and BibTex, but I am having trouble getting the bibliography to work.

With the default pandoc-citeproc I get the error:

```
pandoc-citeproc: Error parsing references: expected [a], encountered Object
```

Which occurs before the .tex file is generated, not during the compilation of the .tex file. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandoc, which doesn't help.

When I add `--biblatex` as a pandoc argument I get a new error that occurs after the .tex file is generated:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.41 We are writing this using LaTeX \autocite
```

If I replace \autocite with \cite in the .tex file it compiles nicely. It would be nice if I could get pandoc/biblatex to use \cite instead of \autocite so I don't have to manually intervene. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Seems like you should use the option `--natbib` then, as suggested here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279739/95109

Comment: See also https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2392. But it is weird that `\autocite` would be undefined when you load `biblatex`. Can you show us a minimal example of a generated `.tex` file (with the call to `biblatex` and all the options)?

Comment: Any news here? Were you able to get things working in the end? Seeing that the question is about pandoc and lacks an MWE as well as the produced `.tex` file, there is not much we can do. I will probably vote to close this question if nothing more happens in due time.