# Converting from Markdown-with-biblatex-commands to LaTeX

Tags: biblatex, citing, pandoc, markdown

How can I use `biblatex` commands *in a Markdown file* (instead of Markdown's native cite commands) and have `pandoc` output a `.tex` file that preserves those `biblatex` commands unchanged?

## question disambiguation

My question is distinct from [one that may sound similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179803/why-doesnt-pandoc-convert-citations-correctly-from-markdown-to-latex), where the issue was how to use Markdown's native citation format (e.g., `[@mycitation, 23]`) and have `pandoc` produce `.tex` output that converted those to `biblatex` commands (e.g., `\autocite[23]{mycitation}`).

Also, to be clear, I am not asking how to have `pandoc` format the citations for me. In other words, I believe that the answer to my question should *not* involve `pandoc-citeproc`.

## motivation

I would like to be able to write in Markdown but take advantage of the range and flexibility of `biblatex-chicago` cite commands, which are far more flexible than Markdown (which, for example, does not have a way to reproduce `\volcite{...}[...]{...}` natively -- that is, without doing it manually as in `@mycitation, vol. 1, p. 23`). I would then like to convert those Markdown files to LaTeX that can be processed with `xelatex` and `biber`.

## MWE

Markdown input:

```
This assertion *must* be cited.^[See \volcite{1}[23]{mycitation}.]
```

Output using `pandoc myfile.md -o myfile.tex` (note the escaped curly braces and square brackets):

```
This assertion \emph{must} be cited.\footnote{See
  \volcite{1}{[}23{]}\{mycitation\}.}
```

Desired `.tex` output:

```
This assertion \emph{must} be cited.\footnote{See \volcite{1}[23]{mycitation}.}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use Pandoc, you can use the [Markdown](https://ctan.org/pkg/markdown?lang=en) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[hybrid,inlineFootnotes]{markdown}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
This assertion *must* be cited.^[See \volcite{1}[23]{mycitation}.]
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

The `hybrid` package option enables the TeX commands, `inlineFootnotes` add support for the footnotes. It supports many of the Pandoc extensions, see the manual.

This is the result:

[image]

It is also supported by `tex4ht`, so you can convert your Markdown + LaTeX document to HTML:

```
make4ht -us filename.tex "fn-in"
```