# Footnotes with full bibliography information

Tags: bibtex, footnotes

I would like to add footnotes, with the text of the .bib file, not only the name of the cite. Found some solutions using jurabib, but my other packages aren't compatible. How could I fix this?

My tex file:

```
    \documentclass[]{report}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage[dutch]{babel}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %Makes Table of Contents clickable

    \begin{document}


    \includecomment{comment} %change exclude to include for showing in pdf too


    % Article top matter
    \title{X} 
    \author{XX}
    \date{\today}  
    \maketitle


    \tableofcontents


    %Begin text

    Text\footnote{name1} more text

    %End text

    \bibliography{pws}{}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}

    \end{document}
```

My bib file:

```
    @misc{name1,
      author = "Name, Name",
      title = "",
      date = "17-05-2014",
      howpublished = "conference"
      }
```

Comment: The question is missing a lot of detail in terms of what you want the final product to look like.  It is hard to provide a detailed answer without this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this type of thing with `biblatex`.  The code below uses `backend=bibtex` option, so you still do the `latex`>`bibtex`>`latex`>`latex` compile routine.  (Though more options are available for bibliographies when using the newer [`biber` backend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8411/47522).)

You don't mention requirements for numbering and/or still printing these citations in a bibliography at the end of the document.  Thus, this is a basic version that illustrates how to get started.

`biblatex` provides the `\footcite` command that allows you to also specify text to go before or after the citation itself: `\footcite[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<key>}`.  See more in [the documentation (`\footcite` appears on page 80)](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{name1,
  author = "Name, Name",
  title = "",
  date = "17-05-2014",
  howpublished = "conference"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
%\usepackage{cite} % Not compatible with biblatex
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %Makes Table of Contents clickable

\begin{document}

Text\footcite[See][pages 1--2]{name1} more text

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Footnote citation looks like this:

[image: footnote]