# Getting the citation style right

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I need to achieve a specific style of citing which I can't seem to recreate with biblatex. I'd be happy if you could help me with this:

Citations have to be numeric superscript with footnotes containing the author year and page.

> This is an example sentence<sup>1</sup>.

And the footnote has to look like this:

> <sup>1</sup>Pallhuber 1978, S. 75

Bibliography:

> Surname, Lastname: Title, Publisher, Year

Comment: Hello, please post a compilable code snippet so we can help you using your code as base work. Could [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180309/footnotes-with-full-bibliography-information) help ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to BambOo I found my solution:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,
citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Using `\footcite[page 16]{book}`

Comment: Is there any reason why you use `style=numeric, citestyle=authoryear-icomp,` and not the more conventional  `style=authoryear-icomp,`? It makes little sense to have the numbers in the bibliography if they are not used in the text.