# Using commas in \cite

Tags: citing, cite-package

I am using two packages `\usepackage{cite}` and `\usepackage{chicago}` 
to create the appropriate references. Using the command `\cite(ref)` delivers the output of, e.g., (Smith 2015), but I need to insert a comma into it to get (Smith, 2015). How could I do it without switching to the `natbib` package. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What might be the reason for not wanting to load the `natbib` citation management package?

Comment: According to the user guide of the `cite` package, it is meant to be used to generate numeric-style citation call-outs. I woudn't use it for authoryear-style citation call-outs.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that indeed it is not handy to use the cite package for authoryear-style citation. Have switched to natbib instead.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a solution with `cite` (and apparently settled with `natbib` instead), but I want to suggest you consider migrating to [**`biblatex`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex) as a replacement for bibtex in the future. See:

- [What to do to switch to biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091)
- [What is the difference between bibtex and biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8411)
- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701)
- [biblatex in a nutshell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)

There's even a [`biblatex-chicago`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex-chicago) package to produce citations and bibliographies compliant with the *Chicago Manual of Style*, although the standard author-date styles are often more than enough.

The following MWE, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,strict]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocites{aristotle:physics,cicero,companion,bertram}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

would output

> [image: minimal working example sample]