# How to move page number?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I want to change the position of the page number.

I've read around here that some people suggest using the [`fancyhdr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package, but I don't want to use it – I'm a beginner to LaTeX so I don't want to use a package that could change the margins and other specifications to the layout that I've already made. Does anyone know how to move the page number?

Please correct me if my concerns about `fancyhdr` are unfounded.

Comment: What documentclass do you use? And what pagestyle? And where do you want to move the pagenumber to?

Comment: `fancyhdr` didn't change any margin ... However, what documentclass you are using?

Comment: Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DGVEJvzX.

Comment: You'll see that I used \thispagestyle{empty}
  \pagestyle{empty} just so that I could remove the page number until I found a way to move it...

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen -- I want to move the page number to the bottom right or left hand corner of the page.

Answer (score 39):

As a beginner you *should* be using packages, and making use of them as much as possible.  Generally speaking, packages don't mess up things that they are not designed to change, so you shouldn't be worrying much about using them, especially if they are the kinds of packages that are recommended often by users here.  Unless you are using a special documentclass such as `memoir` or one of the KOMA classes, you *should* be using `fancyhdr`, because it provides a very simple interface to do exactly what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for showing some sample text
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\rfoot{\thepage}
%
%lfoot{\thepage} % puts it on the left side instead
%
% or if your document is 2 sided, and you want even and odd placement of the number
%\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % Left side on Even pages; Right side on Odd pages
%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The best reason to use a package is that package writers are generally *much* more experienced in doing things than the average end user, and so a package will deal with problems that might not even occur to you (even when you become more experienced with LaTeX); also, there's really no sense in re-inventing the wheel, when good tools with long track records of use are available.

See also [this page on the Wiki](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553/2693)  for some recommendations of useful packages. Since you also mentioned changing margins, you should also probably be using the `geometry` package instead of doing that by hand, too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I guess I was under the impression that if there were conflicting environments (namely if the package had different arguments than the ones I had), then my document would look messed up. I will try using fancyhdr and what you recommended above to resolve my issue. Also, if you saw the my earlier comments to Herbert and Harald, I am using a geometry package for margins. Actually, I posted my code in one of the above comments.

Comment: @Halime However, you *should* look at the console output if you use `fancyhdr` to set *headers* because it will tell you if the headers take more space than is available, and will specify the minimum height required if they do. You then feed that information to `geometry` to avoid unexpected changes to your page layout. But this is a *good* thing because it is a change you *need* to make if you are using headers which are too big for the available space!

Comment: *"As a beginner you should be using packages, and as much as possible."* this might be confusing, since we tell people not to use that much packages. Rule of thumb should be to load/use the package one *actually* needs. Having a 5000 line preamble loading almost every package on CTAN seems counterintuitive.

Comment: @Johannes_B I think this is a bit of English confusion. "and as much as possible" here means that you should *use* them as much as possible not you should use as *many* as possible. But I can change the wording to make it clearer.

Comment: Oh yes, confusion on my part. Now that you made it clear, i was confusing much and many. But as far as i heard, native english speakers sometimes confuse that as well (would like to know if this is true) and we have many non-native speakers around. I think a little clarification would be nice.

Comment: @Johannes_B I've made the wording clearer. I don't think native speakers typically replace 'many' with 'much'. What they do do, which is similar, is replace 'fewer' (the correspondent of 'many') with 'less' (the correspondent of 'much'.  Perhaps that the one you have in mind. Note the careful linguist wording of 'replace' rather than 'confuse'. :)

Answer (score 14):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@myPS{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\null\hfill\thepage}
    \def\@evenfoot{\thepage}%
    \def\@evenhead{\null\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}}}%
\makeatother

\pagestyle{myPS}

\begin{document}

foo
\clearpage
blah
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try that (as well as Alan Munn's response) to see if that will work for me.

Comment: @Herbert, I managed to move the page number to the right side of footer by controlling `rofoot` and `refoot` in koma-script packages. However, I have a problem of accurately specifying the distance between the page number and margins. So, I would be grateful if you could consider my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/322024/2288

Comment: see my answer to your question

Comment: This worked much better than fancyhdr for me because my document has multiple page sizes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely agree [with Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8847/277964) with one limitation: His answer might give the impression that the `fancyhdr` package is without alternative. However, there are some other packages to configure the page header and page footer.

Here I've adapted his example for using [package `scrlayer-scrpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) instead of `fancyhdr`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for showing some sample text
\clearpairofpagestyles% remove all default elements from page styles scrheadings
                      % and plain.scrheadings
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% add pagination to the outer part of the page footer
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: pagination on the right side of the footer using scrlayer-scrpage]

Using `scrlayer-scrpage` would also be recommended using a KOMA-Script class like `scrartcl` instead of a standard class:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for showing some sample text
\cfoot*{}% remove the default center pagination from the footer
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% add pagination to the outer part of the page footer
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I've used here another solution to remove the default pagination in the middle of the footer. You can find more examples for using `scrlayer-scrpage` in the manual and [in the KOMA-Script wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_PageHeadFoot/) (also available [in German](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_PageHeadFoot/)).

For such a simple page style with pagination only, you could also use [package `scrlayer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for showing some sample text
\DeclareNewLayer[% declare a new layer
  foreground,% printed in the foreground
  foot,% placed to the page footer
  contents={\hfill\thepage}% with right aligned page number as content
]{pagenumber}
\RedeclarePageStyleByLayers{plain}{pagenumber}% redefine page style plain to use the newly defined layer
\pagestyle{plain}% (re)activate the (re)defined page style
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

As you can see, package `scrlayer` is more low-level than `scrlayer-scrpage`. Package `scrlayer-scrpage` adds an extra user level to package `scrlayer`.

Here I've adapted his example for using [package `titleps`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps) instead of `fancyhdr`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for showing some sample text
\newpagestyle{pagenumberfooterright}{% defining a new page style
  \setfoot{}{}{\thepage}% with page number at the right side
}
\pagestyle{pagenumberfooterright}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: page number at the right side of the footer with titleps]

See the manuals of the packages for more information.