# Page numbering at top of page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize headers and footers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/how-to-customize-headers-and-footers)

How would I put my name and the page on my CV just like the image below? I would like to do it like the image below from the 2nd page onwards. i.e. From page 2 onwards, it would say my name and the page number.

Also, how would I get rid of the page numbering at the bottom of each page in my cv (see my latex code below).

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, lipsum, bibentry}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}

\title{\bfseries\Huge John Doe}
\author{}
\date{}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Address Line 1\\
Address Line 2\\
Address Line 3\\
Address Line 4\\
Address Line 5
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Mobile: 123-456789\\
Email: myemail@gmail.com\\
Date of Birth: 01/01/2012\\
Citizenship: My citizenship
\end{minipage}
\vspace{20pt}

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008--2012&MSc in Computer Science, Great University, Country.\vspace{5pt}\\
2006--2008&BSc in Life Science, Great University, Country.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Employment}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2011--today&{\bf Company Name.} Head of Department. Add my job description here. Add my job description here. Add my job description here. Add my job description here.\\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\end{itemize} 
\end{tabular}

\section*{Awards and Achievements}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&Gold medal.\vspace{5pt}\\
2006&Silver medal.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Organisational Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&This event.\vspace{5pt}\\
\end{tabular}


\section*{Languages}
English, Spanish, French, German


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can load the `scrpage2`-package from the [koma-script-bundle](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script). `\maketitle` has hard coded a `\thispagestyle{plain}`, Which gives you page number centred at bottom.  To get rid of the page number at page one, place `\thispagestyle{empty}` *after* the `\maketitle`-command.

`scrpage2` is documented at page 196 in the English manual (chapter 5).

And MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, lipsum, bibentry}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrbase,scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} % pagestyle with page number

\title{\bfseries\Huge John Doe}
\author{}
\date{}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % place this after \maketitle
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Address Line 1\\
Address Line 2\\
Address Line 3\\
Address Line 4\\
Address Line 5
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Mobile: 123-456789\\
Email: myemail@gmail.com\\
Date of Birth: 01/01/2012\\
Citizenship: My citizenship
\end{minipage}
\vspace{20pt}

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008--2012&MSc in Computer Science, Great University, Country.\vspace{5pt}\\
2006--2008&BSc in Life Science, Great University, Country.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Employment}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2011--today&{\bf Company Name.} Head of Department. Add my job description here. Add my job description here. Add my job description here. Add my job description here.\\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\end{itemize} 
\end{tabular}

\section*{Awards and Achievements}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&Gold medal.\vspace{5pt}\\
2006&Silver medal.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Organisational Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&This event.\vspace{5pt}\\
\end{tabular}

\newpage

\section*{Languages}
English, Spanish, French, German


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks good, may I ask, how would I include my name of the top left?

Comment: @Gary Try `\lohead{My Name}` after `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`.

Answer (score 6):

have a look at the [fancyhdr](ftp://www.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) package. there you can define your headings as you want.

try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{john doe}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage} % set the page number to the haed line
%clean the foot line
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, trying to work with fancyhdr now, might post up another question.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/how-to-move-page-number

Comment: @susisstrolch Generally, an answer pointing out that the question has been answered elsewhere is not an acceptable answer. I know that you don't have enough reputation to flag a question as a duplicate, however, you can always post a link to the other question/answer in a comment to this question. Because the goal of the site is to be as clear as possible and cross-links like this one are non-systematic.