# Page numbers in left and right bottom corners of Book

Tags: page-numbering

There's an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/how-to-move-page-number/8847#8847) that would theoretically address this issue, but the code doesn't seem to be effective - possibly because it's not meant for use with a `book` class document.

What I'd like is to display page numbers alternatively in the bottom left and right corners, and the code below uses `fancyhdr`, but the page numbers are being rendered alternatively in the left margin and the center. Even being in the left and odd in the center (or apparent center).

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}     
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{letterpaper}                   
\usepackage{pdfpages}       
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule

\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % Left side on Even pages; Right side on Odd pages
%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\title{Another Book}
\author{An Author}
\date{}                         
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
\setlength{\footskip}{114pt}
\begin{document}
```

Is there something that's overriding the `\fancyfoot` code?

Comment: Do you really need `\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}`? I guess that it could be the problem. Try to comment it.

Comment: The plain style applies the page number in the center of the foot in the `book` class. You need to redefine `plain` as well.

Comment: Are you including the document using `\includepdf`, or are you creating a document from scratch?

Comment: Actually most of the book is PDF files as it's a book of songs, compiled with `lilypond`. The numbers on those pages are also showing up centered, but that I imagine needs to be addressed separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first page of a chapter uses the `plain` style, as noted in the comments. I've also removed the PDF setting commands as those seem unnecessary, and I've used `\geometry` to set `\footskip`. [Otherwise, `geometry` won't know about the change and won't adjust things appropriately.]

[image: page numbers bottom left and bottom right on two-sided layout]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % Left side on Even pages; Right side on Odd pages
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf[lef,rof]{\thepage}%
}

\title{Another Book}
\author{An Author}
\date{}

\geometry{footskip=114pt}% don't set this manually else geometry won't know!

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \chapter{Some Kant}
  \kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

If you wanted to change the style for the title page, as well, you would need to make an appropriate adjustment. However, it is not usual to include a page number on the title page, so I'm assuming you do not desire this.

Comment: Very nice! Works even on the `\includepdf` pages. Is there something above I could adjust to move the page numbers further out into the margins?

Comment: @MikeiLL `\fancyfootoffset[le,ro]{30pt}` will move the page numbers 30pt into the margin. You need to add it to the redefinition of `plain` and to the `fancy` configuration. Is that what you mean? And, yes, it works fine with `pdfpages` - I use it that way sometimes myself. (But it wasn't relevant to the MWE.)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. What's MWE? Does that refer to the original question? I didn't want to confuse the issue by asking more than one question in a single post.

Comment: @MikeiLL You've escaped this particular piece of jargon so far? Hah! No longer: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). For many questions, an MnWE may be more appropriate (Minimum non-Working Example), although nMWEs are more common (non-Minimal Working Examples) and nMnWnEs are not unheard of (non-Minimal non-Working non-Examples i.e. lots of irrelevant code which won't compile and wouldn't illustrate the problem even if it did). [Note that these descriptors are in no way intended to characterise your questions. I just have a twisted sense of humour.]

Comment: I'm sure there's a acronym for smiling ear to ear and `nMnWnE` definitely got me there. Thanks.