# Remove empty pages from latex [twoside,openright]{book}

Tags: pagestyle

I am writing a report and I would like to begin each chapter with an odd page.

This can be done as in [Page numbers in left and right bottom corners of Book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218766/page-numbers-in-left-and-right-bottom-corners-of-book)

However, this puts empty numbered pages. Is it possible to remove them ?

Best Regards

Comment: So, you want to go from (say) page 3 to page 5 without a blank page 4 in between?  It can be done by redefining `\cleardoublepage` to increment the page counter instead.  I take it you are trying to save paper while printing drafts.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`). By default that prints two sided, starts chapters on odd pages and, if necessary, putting a completely empty blank page before the start of a chapter.

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove white pages (not possible if you want new chapters start on odd pages) OR to remove page numbers from white page? To do the latter just write

```
\usepackage{emptypage}
```

in the preambule.