# Bibliography Total pages?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

How can I indicate in my bibliography that the reference has 500 pages in total, for example.

As I understand, the keyword "pages" in Bibtex refers to the specific page or page ranges.

Comment: Actually I don't know why, but `pagetotal` didn't worked for me. I'm using [ugost2008](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/gost) bibliography style and `numpages` field worked like a charm in my case.

Comment: You must be use bibtex. I was using bibLatex.

Comment: Instead of answering, you should comment on lockstep's answer or on the original question. Anyway, `ugost2008` is a bibtex style bundle, not biblatex (which provides a `pagetotal` field with which its default styles deal).

Comment: @henrique: He is proposing a different, Bibtex-based answer to lockstep: an separate answer is fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex/), you may add a `pagetotal` field to your `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  pagetotal = {999},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: But what about without biblatex? I am using scribtex online compiler - and they don't support it yet...

Comment: @drozzy: Correct -- if (!) you decide to use biblatex, the syntax is different than that of traditional LaTeX/BibTeX. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex/2974#2974) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex) for more details about biblatex.

Comment: oops.. sry I deleted my original comment :-)

Comment: @drozzy: Sadly, I don't know a "traditional" BibTeX style that supports "total pages". Maybe someone else does.

Comment: Thanks, after looking around - it does not seem possible. I will give this a shot.

Comment: Woot - biblatex works!