# How to supress book page totals in latex bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I have a .bib file that includes pagetotal information. How do I surpress that information from being printed when I compile my document.

This is the inverse of the problem here, from which I use the example below

[Bibliography Total pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16504/bibliography-total-pages)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  pagetotal = {999},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two easy ways of doing this:

1. You can use a source map to delete the `pagetotal` field from every entry in your bib file on the fly. I prefer this as the field will never reach `biblatex`.

   ```
   \DeclareSourcemap{
     \maps{
       \map{
         \step[fieldset=pagetotal, null]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. You can clear the field at every bibliography item. This will still leave the field available in citations (although it can be cleared there too).

   ```
   \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{pagetotal}}
   ```

## MWE

You only need one of the options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  pagetotal = {999},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% Option 1: Delete pagetotal field from every entry in bib file
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=pagetotal, null]
    }
  }
}
% Option 2: Clear pagetotal field at every bibliography item
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{pagetotal}}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```