# Custom bibliograpy and citations - general advice needed

Tags: bibliographies

First of all, if a package that implements this kind of citing style, a part of it, or something similar enough to be customized easily already exists, it's great. If it does, what is it called? (apacite is pretty close on the citations part, but does not provide automatic "ibid.")

But that probably is too much to expect. How much effort would be needed to implement it using available tools? What tools should I use? Maybe it is pragmatic to just manually type all citations and bibliography entries? Can I mix these techniques, for example automate formating of books' and articles' entries in bibliography and enter others manually?

I am required to format citations like `(Smith 2012: 134)` where 134 is the page number, also using ibid. for recurring citations and et al. for more than two authors. Dictionaries and Encyclopedias have to be cited like `(Wikipedia 2011 s.v. Physics)`
References style depends on type of the document being reffered, for example, books with listed author(s) should be like `Smith, J. (2012) On pointless regularizations. New York: SomePublishingCompany.` There are about ten categories in total. Most commonly used ones are fairly similar to this example.

I am going to write a report, which will probably be very short (<50 pages even maybe), but several people also use my latex class for the required document layout, and providing a less tedious and more reliable solution for references would be apreciated. I also have nothing against getting to understand LaTeX better, otherwise I probably would just have already started doing it manually.

Comment: have a look at [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). For starters, read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex/2974#2974) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/510).

Comment: If this was an answer, I would accept it, as minimalistic as it is. Biblatex was exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). For starters, read my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex/2974#2974) to [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex) plus [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex).