# What packages are useful for (secondary school) teachers?

Tags: best-practices

I'm trying to bring LaTeX to some of my colleague-teachers (in secondary schools, pupils 12->18 years old).  They all seem quite reluctant to change.

So I'm trying to collect some quick-win situations, that could convince them to 'give it a try'.

What packages exist already that could provide such a quick-win?  Maybe with a brief description?

Comment: I know this seems just another: What packages do exist?-question, I just think there's a lot out there I'm not aware of.

Comment: Teach them tikz and ask to draw some diagrams.

Thinking impartially, you can teach them pstricks, and asymtote also.

Comment: Tikz is a very useful feature, many packages also rely on it. You can check out CTAN, and search for biology or physics iin order to find specialized packages. A quick description is also given to each package.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to collect package names in a list. Everybody might have other preferences in choosing packages and defining a workflow. There are far to many packages, may are too localiced for a big audience.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102878/how-to-convert-tex-illiterate-coworkers-to-latex

Answer (score 4):

`polynoms` for polynomial handling

Advantages:

- Horner Scheme typesetting
- automatic factorisation
- long division-typesetting

Answer (score 2):

`examdoc` for typesetting exams.

Advantages:

- automatic handling of points
- Question and solution are combined, what makes it easier to copy-paste new exams.