# Best Practice (Packages) for a Standard Technical Article With Math and Figures

Tags: best-practices

I am interested in your opinion regarding the recommend packages for a **standard** technical document (Engineering, Physics). I normally use the following header:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Basic Packages for Encoding (Input AND Output) and Langauge Support
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Change Layout with a User-Friendly Interface
\usepackage{geometry}

% Include Pictures with a User-Friendly Interface
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

% Extended Math Support from the Famous 'American Mathematical Society'
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Just for Demonstration Purposes
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

Which leads to

[image]
[image]

I am wondering which other packages are recommended nowadays by the specialists here in this community. I found the following packages and I think they are debatable candidates:

- inputen**x** ([Link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/inputenx))
- xcolor ([Link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor))
- ragged2e ([Link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e))
- fixmath ([Link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixmath))
- fixltx2e ([Link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e))
- mathtools ([Link](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools))
- caption ([Link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption)) and not the *older* caption2 ([Link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption2)) as one could think
- fancyhdr ([Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr))
- biblatex/biber ([Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)) of course for larger documents
- **Update 2020:** xurl (https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl)

I didn't mention `tikz` on purpose. It's great but I don't consider it as a standard package for the average user.

**Important** for me is that packages like `fixltx2e` do normally not require to configure/code much or anything. Which is important for average users.

The class `memoir` ([Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir)) and the `koma-script` classes ([Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)) are very important of course. But I want to discuss this without document classes.

> I am looking for **stable** and good **packages** - not the newest ones. I want to use the information here to help students who are new to LaTeX.

And of course it's always a compromise between *too much packages* and not using the *appropriate packages*.

> I think a collection/list of good packages (that you use very often) with a very brief
>   description would be a good outcome of this question.

**What do you think?**

---

### Reaction so far

- [A one page, dictatorial guide to LATEX packages](https://www.msu.edu/~amunn/latex/latex-guide.pdf) by [alan munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn), last update: April 4, 2015
- Possible duplicate of question: [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex) (user [alan munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn))
- `amssymb` ([Link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts)) and `bm` (access bold symbols in maths mode, [Link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bm)) (user [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif))
- `mathtools` loads `amsmath` (user [bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard))
- One should use `utf8` as the input encoding (which is supported by `biber` and *not* by `bibtex`, user [bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard))
- Using `titleps` ([Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps)) from `titlesec` dis­tri­bu­tion ([Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)) instead of fancyhdr ([Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)) (user [bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard)).
- `fixltx2e` ([Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e)) will be included in the next LaTeX update by default (user [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37907/johannes-b))
- Don't mix `koma-script` classes ([Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)) with `fancyhdr` ([Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)) and `float` ([Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/float)) (user [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37907/johannes-b))
- `cfr-lm` (Enhanced support for the Latin Modern fonts, [Link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cfr-lm)), thumbs up for `fancyhdr`, maybe `enumitem`, `microtype`, `chemformula`  and `siunitx`. `xcolor` is not needed necessarily (I agree, user [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr))

Comment: Is this for an article for a journal? Then for example it is recommended not to change the layout at all as you are only the content provider not the layouter

Comment: Hi. Sorry that I wasn't clear enough. I don't mean a journal paper. Just a general document.

Comment: I think this is basically a duplicate of [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553/2693)

Comment: Then also define *stable*. I tend to use `amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,bm` plus `inputenc,fontenc` in all my docs.

Comment: @daleif: I mean established. Maybe stable is the wrong term :).

Comment: I distribute my My [One Page Dictatorial Guide to LaTeX Packages](http://www.msu.edu/~amunn/latex/latex-guide.pdf) to my students. Since I'm a linguist, it includes lots of specialized packages for linguistics, but all of the basic packages are generic.

Comment: I think you should use `utf8` as input encoding. Note the `biber` understands utf8, unlike `bibtex`. `mathtools` is a highly recommendable extension of `amsmath`, and it's point less to load amsmath, since mathtools does it for you. Personally, I prefer to use `titleps`, from `titlesec` rather than `fancyhdr` (easier to customise, in my opinion).

Comment: Rule of thumb, to use as few packages as possible, but as much as necessary. Depending on the doc-class, that can be more or less (thinking of `memoir`). As a KOMA-user, i wouldn't dare to load package `float` or `fancyhdr`, not even in my worst nightmare.

Comment: With the next LaTeX-update, you will have the `fixltx2e` updates by default. ;-)

Comment: Thinking about it, this question is quite opinion based or too broad. I never load `inputenc` or `fontenc`. In contrast to @Alan, i don't need *linguistigs* stuff, but packages like `chemformula`, `booktabs` or `siunitx`.

Comment: And last but not least, please, *please* don't make some kind of template. Do it for Gunnar.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thanks for your comments. I thing inputenc and fontenc are important for 'everybody'. For example if you have 'Umlaute' or other special characters in your text. If you do it wrong then in some cases you cannot search for these characters in the resulting PDF as far as I know.

Comment: XeTeX and LuaTeX are unicode aware engines. If your input is utf8-encoded, which is the common default nowadays, you don't have to care about package `inputenc`. Package `fontspec` deals with font encoding stuff.

Comment: I like `fancyhdr`. (Just saying because it seems to be getting a hard time here.) I also almost always load `cfr-lm` (possibly to be expected). I wouldn't think `xcolor` was needed in a typical article. I always load `babel` and it is probably better to specify the variant of English for clarity. I also always load `enumitem` and `microtype`. But this is all very, very dependent on what you ***need***. That a package is stable and good is no reason to load it if you don't need it. `chemformula` and `siunitx` may be excellent but I've never used them because I don't need them.

Comment: Can you add some explanations on what you think misses? The question , or rather the answer, will be opinion based. Linguists will load linguistics packages, physicists package `physics` chemists package `chemformula` mathematicians package `mathtools` engineers a wild mixture of the above. May i ask about the intention of the question? You are always welcome in our little chat.

Comment: There is also a [more general question on often loaded packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553/25077). This is clearly not a duplicate!

Comment: @strpeter Thx! I will look into it.

Comment: I don't agree with @AlanMunn's dictatorial guide! Note, too, that it depends where you are. If you are writing American English, you may not need `babel`. If you are writing anything else, you are best using it.

Comment: @cfr That's why it's dictatorial. :). It probably needs some revision, but other than `babel` which for most of my students isn't a concern what other things would you change?

Comment: @AlanMunn I wouldn't even tell them about `applemac` and stuff. I'd tell them to use `utf8` with an editor which supports it. And I wouldn't give `natbib`, `multicol`, `parskip` or `setspace` as essential or always-load, for sure. I'm allergic to `titlesec` but if I was recommending it, I'd recommend `titleps` rather than `fancyhdr`. I'd also at least mention `forest` and probably `mathtools` rather than `amsmath`. I'd probably list the KOMA classes rather than `memoir` but that's presumably personal preference. `memoir`'s documentation annoys me is all. I'd add `textcomp`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Also, I realise that's why it is dictatorial. But, fortunately, I'm not subject to your dictatorship and can therefore disagree with a certain degree of impunity (and equally dictatorial views, no doubt).

Comment: You need none of the mentioned packages, the `\input opmac` is sufficient. See opmac-prospectus: http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-letak.pdf

Comment: @wipet Come on that's the definition of a package :) Don't hide behind the plain TeX syntax.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just ran a workshop on LaTeX for postgraduate students. Here is the list of packages which I recommended they all load in every document:

```
%
```

This is, I think, the right answer. This is not to say that I did not tell them about packages - I did. Nor is it to say that I made no recommendations - I did. But I made ***conditional recommendations***. I wanted them to understand that packages extend LaTeX in particular ways. You load them ***if you need those extensions***. I also made ***very few*** such recommendations.

This workshop was introductory. It assumed no prior experience with LaTeX. No participant had used LaTeX before. (One had used Scientific Word but had never seen LaTeX code.)

When I run the follow-up, I plan to recommend loading a small number of packages routinely. Right now, my planned list includes the following

- `babel` with `british` or `welsh` or `welsh,british` passed to the document class;
- `inputenc` with option `utf8`;
- `fontenc` with option `T1`.

I will also, probably, give them a list of 'what if I want to...?' with suggested packages, and I may try to give them a list of discipline-specific packages, if I can manage it or if I can get people here to volunteer the information.

Why so minimal? Because the huge temptation is to add packages with abandon, and the result is a mess. Better to load fewer packages initially, as a beginner, and learn which ones you need later.

Note that this is very different from the list of packages which I always, or almost always, load. Even if I cleaned up my code (which I should), that list would be a significant one. But I know why I load those packages, I'm aware that I load them, and I have at least some sense of some of the problems they may cause. I want custom page layouts and diagrams and finer-grained control over fonts and microtypography and fancy cross-references and other fiddly bits. Those are not, in my view, things which somebody who has just started to use LaTeX should be thinking about.

I realise that this is not the answer you want. It is, however, the answer which I think is correct. I may be wrong but, for whatever it is worth, that is what I recommend.

Perhaps I should also say that, if I had not been answering questions here for a while, my list of recommendations would have been much closer to the list of packages I use. That would, I think, have been a bad thing - indeed, I am convinced that it would have been a Bad Thing - and so I think that my answer is at least a minimally informed one.

## EDIT

At the intermediate workshop I'm scheduled to run in June, I *do* plan to give students a conditional package list.

### *I would on **NO** account give this to students when introducing LaTeX.*

Right now, my draft list looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,welsh,british,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[tt=lining]{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{enumitem,geometry,url,fancyref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
   \MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
   \MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}
\geometry{scale=.9}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\urlstyle{sf}
\title{\LaTeX{} Package Recommendations}
\author{cfr}
\date{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf[cf]{%
  Find packages in the Comprehensive \TeX{} Archive Network (CTAN) at \url{ctan.org}.
  Browse by topic at \url{ctan.org/topic}.}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\pdfinfo{%
  /Title    (LaTeX Package Recommendations)
  /Subject  (LaTeX)
  /Keywords (LaTeX, package)}
\maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}
\newlist{pkgdescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[pkgdescription]{font=\bfseries\ttfamily}
\newcommand*\lpack[1]{\texttt{\bfseries #1}}
\section{General}
You should almost always use:
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[babel] Pass \verb|welsh,british| to your class.
  \item[inputenc] Load with option \verb|utf8|; \verb|\input{ix-utf8enc.dfu}|.
  \item[fontenc] Load with option \verb|T1|.
  \item[textcomp]
  \item[microtype]
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Document Layout}
If you are using a standard class (e.g.\ \lpack{article}, \lpack{book} or \lpack{report}):
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[geometry] to change page dimensions.
  \item[fancyhdr] for custom headers/footers.
  \item[footmisc] for customised footnotes.
  \item[titling] to use document metadata after \verb|\maketitle|.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Mathematics}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[mathtools] for enhanced \lpack{amsmath}.
  \item[amssymb] for more symbols, scripts.
  \item[ntheorem] for enhanced theorem environments.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Quotes \& Quoting}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[csquotes] for context- and language-sensitive quotations and quotation marks. Recommended if using \lpack{biblatex}.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Citations \& Bibliographies}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[biblatex] Load with option \verb|backend=biber|.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Cross-Referencing}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[fancyref] for enhanced cross-references.
  \item[cleverref] for enhanced cross-references.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Lists}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[enumitem] for custom lists.
  \item[glossaries] for glossaries and lists of acronyms.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Tables}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[array] for enhanced tabular environments.
  \item[booktabs] for professional quality tables.
  \item[longtable] for multi-page tables.
  \item[tabularx] for tables with specified width.
  \item[threeparttable] for tables with notes.
  \item[multirow] for cells spanning multiple rows.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Floats}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[caption] to customise captions.
  \item[float] more options for floats.
  \item[subcaption] for sub-figures, sub-tables and sub-captions.
  \item[floatrow] for aligned sub-figures.
  \item[rotating] to rotate floats.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Hyperlinks}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[hyperref] for hyperlinks.
  \item[bookmark] for enhanced bookmarks.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Images \& Colour}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[graphicx] to load external images.
  \item[xcolor] for colour.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Diagrams}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[tikz] for diagrams.
  \emph{Many} specialised extensions available.
  \item[pgfplots] for plots.
  Includes \lpack{pgfplotstable} for data tables.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{External Data}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[datatool] for data manipulation.
  \item[textmerg] for merging text.
\end{pkgdescription}
\section{Version Control}
\begin{pkgdescription}
  \item[svn-multi] for use with \verb|subversion|.
  \item[gitinfo2] for use with \verb|git|.
\end{pkgdescription}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

I've decided to add a second page with discipline-specific packages. Hence, `turnstile` and `forest` have been removed from my general list. The above now represents the first page which lists general packages. The next page is currently the subject of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237100/which-packages-should-i-recommend-to-postgraduates-in-different-academic-discipl) and so I'm removing that part of the code from here, since it is not relevant to the core of this question anyway.

Here is the first page of the handout:

[image: general package recommendations for intermediate users]

Thanks to [ManuelKuehner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14649/manuel) for adding screen shots from an earlier version of this answer.

Comment: I really like this answer, and I agree with it almost completely. I also realize from your comments about my dictatorial guide that you took mine to be much more of a "you must load these packages" list, whereas I intended it to be much more like your "what if I want to..." list. So I'll adjust my wording accordingly. Thanks. (Also, my use of 'dictatorial' is reflecting the fact that I don't justify my choices; I don't require my students to use anything (or LaTeX at all, for that matter.))

Comment: @cfr Thanks a lot for your thoughts. And indeed, that's not the answer I was looking for. I assume we just have different opinions and/or experiences on the subject. I upvote it of course - since it is a good answer - but I won't award it with the bounty :) (no hard feelings, ok?! :). And thanks for mentioning the 'forest' package.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks. That makes sense to me. I also got a lot of 'what if I want to?' questions, so individual students also got recommendations responding to those. (In one case, a recommendation for something I've never even used but which I hope will work!)

Comment: @ManuelKuehner Fine with me. I half expected you to down vote it, to be honest. `forest` is great.

Comment: @cfr -- since you incorporate `amsmath` with `mathtools, you should do the same with `amsfonts` -- it is loaded by `amssymb`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I always manage to forget that.

Comment: Just saw that answer now, very very good. I agree completely.

Comment: I don't like the `float` package very much... Nevertheless: `newfloat` (from the same author as `caption`) does some of the things `float` does. (otherwise good list :) )

Comment: @clemens Why not `float`? (I'm not disagreeing - I'm just not very familiar with the options in this area.)

Comment: @cfr basically I don't like it because it provides the `H` specifier but also because it has far less options when declaring a new float.

Comment: Note that the final version is posted [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248476/) (looks identical, mind). @clemens You may be right. I can't change it for this time, though. I do think that fewer options may be an advantage with more inexperienced users. Some packages are excellent but just too much for beginners. These users may only have been using LaTeX for a couple of months.

Comment: @cfr maybe it's not necessary to change it. Certainly not just because *I* don't like `float`... :)

Comment: What of this packages are not needed anymore if we use memoir or KOMA?

Comment: I think there is a typo in package name: it should be "cleveref" instead of "clever**r**ef":)

Comment: @andselisk You are quite right. Indeed. Thank-you! Now, should I edit for that or wait ... and, if I wait, will I forget ...?

Comment: Is your workshop on LaTeX for postgraduate students available online?