# texlive packages to know?

Tags: texlive, ctan

texlive now has about 150,000 files, and thousands of packages.  I obviously don't know the vast majority.  I only know what I regularly use.  A long time ago, the LaTeX Companion was my bible, but the most recent edition was so long and is so old by now that I had to give up on this one, too.

is there a list of "most important" and "most popular" packages that I should be aware of but am not yet aware of?  unfortunately, there is no "public use" counter for latex packages :-( .

I did a quick scan through my hundreds of latex files over the years to identify my own list of most used packages, which contain

- amsmath
- array
- babel
- booktabs
- caption
- color
- float
- graphicx
- hyperref
- microtype
- needspace
- rotating
- setspace
- ulem
- url
- xcolor

I would consider latex almost useless without about half of these packages.  I also use beamer and tikz, too---not as often, but important.  (I am still keeping an eye on lualatex and context; and every two decades, I am checking back on latex3.)

I think novices and experts would both benefit from a list of "need-to-know" great packages for latex users.  what other essential common packages that every latex user should know did I not list?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553/21344

Comment: surely you only need the packages [in this list](https://www.ctan.org/author/carlisle) :)

Comment: surely it is still too many to study :( (at least for me)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Oh my, you've written packages? ;-) Till now I have known you only as being a talented MS Pain(t) artist ;-)

Comment: thanks for the pointer to the original question.  wasn't easy to locate for me, so this dead question with the link is a good thing.