# How to prevent uneven spacing between words

Tags: math-mode, spacing, multicol

In the following example, I get awkward spacing in a multicol environment in the second question. Notice that the words "Which of the following" are not spaced as they are in the first question. I'd rather have the spacing be even and have some blank space at the end of the line. Keep in mind I need two columns in this document.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[inner=1.1in,outer=.7in,top=.9in,bottom=1in,paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\raggedcolumns
\begin{enumerate}

\item For ${i = \sqrt{-1}}$, which of the following is equivalent to $(5 - 3i) - (-2 + 5i)$? % C
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}

\item Which of the following is equal to ${(5 + 2i)(5 - 2i)}$? (Note: $i = \sqrt{-1}$) % B
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\raggedright` makes lines ragged as requested

Comment: Why multicols* and not multicols?

Comment: multicols halves the content so that both columns contain text. I want multicols* because if there isn't enough content for both columns, then it should be restricted to the first column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When typesetting material in narrow columns, it's frequently advisable to give up on full justification and, instead, to go for a "ragged-right" (aka: flushleft) look. To achieve this look for the entire document, load the `ragged2e` package with the option `document`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[inner=1.1in,outer=.7in,top=.9in,bottom=1in,
            letterpaper,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,multicol}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}  % <- new

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\raggedcolumns

\begin{enumerate}

\item For ${i = \sqrt{-1}}$, which of the following 
is equivalent to $(5 - 3i) - (-2 + 5i)$? % C
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}

\item Which of the following is equal to 
${(5 + 2i)(5 - 2i)}$? (Note: $i = \sqrt{-1}$\,) % B
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As often, `microtype` is your friend.

A short explanation of what it does [is there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586/34551), you might want to look at the documentation, too (`texdoc microtype` comes with magnificent examples of what it does, if opened with a recent pdfviewer).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[inner=1.1in,outer=.7in,top=.9in,bottom=1in,paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype} % Load this package to obtain a fine composition.

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\raggedcolumns
\begin{enumerate}

\item For ${i = \sqrt{-1}}$, which of the following is equivalent to $(5 - 3i) - (-2 + 5i)$? % C
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}

\item Which of the following is equal to ${(5 + 2i)(5 - 2i)}$? (Note: $i = \sqrt{-1}$) % B
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: While this approach happens to work for the code given by the OP, it's of no help if the word "equal" in the second item wer replaced with "equivalent". As such, the generality of the proposed approach is limited.

Comment: @Mico : I definitely agree, but loading `microtype` in general avoids a lot of troubles of the kind Op encounters. And it is what I would consider to be a good practice.