# Make >>> a keyword in listings enviorment

Tags: listings, python

I'm new to LaTeX. I want to show Python code in an article.

The idea is to change de color of the `>>>` symbol.

When I use `<@\textcolor{red}{my_text}@>` and write a text in my_text variable, it works and change the color. But when my_text is `>>>` it shows ¿¿¿.

How can I show `>>>` in blue, for exemple. I've already tried changing `morekeywords= variable`. And didn't work too.

Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{color}

\lstset{
    language=Python,            
    columns=flexible,       
    escapeinside={<@}{@>},
    frame=lines
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Python Console, 
                    label=amb,  numbers=none]
<@\textcolor{blue}{>>>}@> print(Hello World)
<@\textcolor{red}{Hello World}@>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the `>` symbol does not occur in the default text font (computer modern), only in the symbol font.  you can get the symbol with `\texttt{>>>}` without entering math mode, if you're happy with the "typewriter" style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* add `>>>` with `morekeywords` but you also have to change `>` to be a letter with the `alsoletter` option for it to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language = Python ,            
  columns = flexible ,       
  escapeinside = {<@}{@>} ,
  frame = lines ,
  alsoletter = > ,
  morekeywords = {>>>}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Python Console, label=amb, numbers=none]
>>> print(Hello World)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want it blue *but not all keywords blue* you can add it to a different class of keywords and set a style for said class by using the optional argument of the corresponding options:

```
morekeywords = [2]{>>>} ,
keywordstyle = [2]\color{blue}\bfseries
```

[image]

As soon as you add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` ([which in general is a good idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664)) to the example you won't be happy anymore, though:

[image]

`>>` is turned into `»` (as a ligature) then. In that case personally I'd use teletype as font for the code (I'd do that in any case, but that's just me) with `basicstyle = \ttfamily`:

[image]

Since now the keywords no longer are bold we need to use a teletype font that has a bold series, eg with `\usepackage{lmodern}`:

[image]

If you don't want teletype code but still want to use `T1` encoding and if you don't need `>>` to be treated as a ligature anywhere else in your document you could also add the `microtype` package and disable the ligature

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[>]{encoding = T1}
```

([Using the `microtype` package will do your document good, anyway…](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553#586))

### without teletype:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[>]{encoding = T1}

\lstset{
  language = Python ,            
  columns = flexible ,       
  escapeinside = {<@}{@>} ,
  frame = lines ,
  alsoletter = > ,
  morekeywords = [2]{>>>} ,
  keywordstyle = [2]\color{blue}\bfseries
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Python Console, label=amb, numbers=none]
>>> print(Hello World)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### with teletype:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[>]{encoding = T1}

\lstset{
  basicstyle = \ttfamily ,
  language = Python ,            
  columns = flexible ,       
  escapeinside = {<@}{@>} ,
  frame = lines ,
  alsoletter = > ,
  morekeywords = [2]{>>>} ,
  keywordstyle = [2]\color{blue}\bfseries
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Python Console, label=amb, numbers=none]
>>> print(Hello World)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to switch the font encoding, using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. This changes a textmode `>` into an actual `>` sign, rather than `¿`.

This also parses `>>` into a guillemet `»`, but you can fix this by separating them like this: `>{}>{}>`.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- here
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    language=Python,
    escapeinside={<@}{@>},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
<@\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{>{}>{}>}}@> print(Hello World) % <-- here
<@\textcolor{red}{Hello World}@>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]