# What are the classes and packages that must exist in a simple Latex file

Tags: packages, document-classes

I am a new Latex user and I have this question: What are the classes and packages that must exist in a simple Latex file?

Books recommendation are so appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please take a look at the postings [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553/5001) and [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5001)

Comment: I'm not clear at all what you mean here: as @Mico says perhaps 'what do people commonly load' but that's only one possible interpretation!

Comment: Incidentally, there can only be one `\documentclass` instruction per LaTeX document. Which document class you *should* use greatly depends on your typesetting needs -- about which, alas, you haven't told us anything so far.

Comment: yes I exactly meant what Mico said. @JosephWright

Comment: One definition of a "simple" LaTeX file could be a file that loads no packages at all. But in practice there are some packages that are needed for almost any real document.

Comment: A simple file could even not load any document class: `\def\normalsize{\normalfont}
\begin{document} Hello, {\em baby} \end{document}`  From here it depends of what you need.