# Quotation Mark Pairing

Tags: punctuation

How do you force LaTeX to treat three closing quotation marks as the first one being a single-mark, the last two being a double mark?

This is important when a quote within a quote ends as follows:

```
``the cat 'sat on the mat'''.
```

This renders:

```
'' '.
```

But I want it to render:

```
' ''.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
``Testing `one, two, three'''.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend to use the `csquotes` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Testing \enquote{one, two, three}}.
\end{document}
```

This package is configurable with respect to the style of the quotation. Compare, for example, version A

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Testing \enquote{one, two, three}}.
\end{document}
```

[image: option style=british]

with version B

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Testing \enquote{one, two, three}}.
\end{document}
```

[image: option style=american]

In most cases, the combination of `babel` and `csquotes` using the `autostyle=true` option of `csquotes` is just fine.

Answer (score 6):

As two following single quotation marks are always merged, you can use a space in input. That will give the desired output.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
``Testing `one, two, three' ''.
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you prefer very small space, you could use (not in LuaLaTeX, thanks to Harald Hanche-Olsen)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
``Testing `one, two, three'{}''.
\end{document}
```

And last method (suggested by Knuth in the TeXbook and by barbara beeton in the comments):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
``Testing `one, two, three'\,''.
\end{document}
```

Comment: In luatex, inserting an empty group `{}` does not inhibit ligatures, so your second alternative doesn't work there. You can fix that with a zero length space, instead: `…three'\kern0pt''`. This has the added advantage that adjusting the amount of space is trivial. (But of course, with luatex, you can just use the proper quotes directly, avoiding the whole issue.)

Comment: in the texbook, knuth recommends using `\,` for the space.

Comment: `\,` is also recommended in Leslie Lamport's LaTeX: A Document Preparation System

Answer (score 5):

I let csquotes handle this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\enquote{Testing \enquote{one, two, three}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mt{\kern 0.083335em}
\begin{document}

% A poor's man solution without packages
``Testing `one, two, three'\mt''.

% Or ...
\textquotedblleft
    Testing 
    \textquoteleft
        one, two, three%
    \textquoteright\mt
\textquotedblright.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain? That `\kern` number looks very arbitrary.

Comment: @AaronHall 0.083335em is exactly one half  `\thinspace`. At glance  seem to fit with the space used with `csquotes` ( I have not searched in the source code of the package, maybe is not exactly the same).

Comment: Still seems arbitrary. Why one-half of a `\thinspace`?

Comment: @AaronHall Why not? Why  `\thinspace` is one-sith part of em (`.16667em`) instead of  one-tenth of pi logarithm (`.114473em`) or something else? Is the same space used in `csquotes`, the smallest standard spacing (`\thinspace`) seem to large for this and one quarter is hardly noticed.  But if this is not convincing, nothing prevents you from changing it.