# Could not able to label the label the equation in latex

Tags: math-mode, equations, journal-publishing

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.3cm, right=1.3cm, top=1.5 cm, bottom=1.2cm] {geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf,caption,subfigure}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{microtype} % For justification
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text, remove in your own document
\usepackage{geometry} % to change margins
\usepackage{pdflscape} % provides the landscape environment
\usepackage{ragged2e} % provides \RaggedLeft
\usepackage{amsmath,multirow,float,setspace,indentfirst}
\doublespacing
% below are for flow chart
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
\tikzstyle{intt}=[draw,text centered,minimum size=6em,text width=5.25cm,text height=0.34cm,fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{intl}=[draw,text centered,minimum size=2em,text width=2.75cm,text height=0.34cm]
\tikzstyle{int}=[rectangle,rounded corners,minimum size=2.5em,text centered,text width=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{intg}=[draw,minimum size=3em,text centered,text width=6.cm,fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{sum}=[draw,shape=circle,inner sep=2pt,text centered,node distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{summ}=[drawshape=circle,inner sep=4pt,text centered,node distance=3.cm]
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!50]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]


\begin{document}

 \begin{equation} \label{eq:funcao_dif} 
        E_{i}\,I_{i}\,\frac{\partial ^4\,Y_{i}(\bar{x},t)}{\partial\bar{x}^4}+\rho_{i}\,A_{i}\frac{\partial ^2\,Y_{i}(\bar{x},t)}{\partial t^2}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\,k_{j,l}\big(Y_{i}(\bar{\zeta}_{j},t))\,\bar{\delta}(\bar{x}-\bar{\zeta_{j}})+k_{j,r}\big(\frac{\partial Y_{i}(\bar{\zeta}_{j},t)}{\partial \bar{x}}\big)\,\bar{\delta}'(\bar{x}-\bar{\zeta_{j}})
 \end{equation}


    The solution of the  \eqref{eq:funcao_dif}  


\end{document}
```

I know that I have lots of packages that, I am writing a technical paper I need math packages. Now I have an equation I want to label it but the `\eqref` is not working. This question is already answered in the forum but I don't know what are the packages which are creating conflict between each other? **And also I want to know what are the packages best suited for writing a journal paper**

Comment: The `refstyle` package provides a definition of `\eqref` which is incompatible with the definition provided by the `amsmath` package. Are you sure you need to load the `refstyle` package?

Comment: Indeed a lot of packages, just try to remove as many as possible of them to get to the source of the problem (i.e. the interfering package when there is one). When I run the example with pdflatex I get a the warning: `LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:eq:funcao_dif' on page 1 undefined on input line 48` and also the error `! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable
fonts.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv

l.51 \end{document}`
8.

Comment: and any comments on my questions which is in bold?

Comment: Regarding the last question, have a look  at [What packages do people load by default in latex ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex/2974#2974) as a starting point

Comment: The question in bold can only be answered in a highly subjective way -- which is discouraged on this site. Rather than worry about which the "best" packages may be for "writing a journal paper", I would focus my attention on getting rid of the cruft in the preamble. No need to load packages more than once, for instance.

Comment: Interestingly, it appears that if you remove the `eq:` prefix in your label, it works fine, although some warning still appear

Comment: @BambOo I don't get the warning anymore at that moment but the error remains.

Comment: @albert Even more surprisingly, I re-started from the OP's snippet an I am not able to reproduce the working code ... Amazing LaTeX ;)

Comment: In addition to my previous comment and to @Mico's, packages are to be loaded only if you need them. There are some highly general and used packages (see my former comment) which are very often (not always) useful. However, a lot of other packages are meant to be loaded when needed only.

Comment: as you asked for comments on package use, `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}` don't use `[pdftex]` option (let it choose the right option automatically)  `{epstopdf` you probably don't need that (`graphicx` calls the main part of it automatically when needed), `\usepackage{t1enc}` use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` instead. Don't use `\doublespacing` in a technical paper and only use it in a thesis if you are mandated to use it by the university regulations. Don't use `\justifying` except in the very rare case that you need to over-ride a `\raggedright`

Comment: @BambOo Thanks for your suggestions, but removed some of the packages and I am still getting the same thing

Comment: @vijay as adised by Mico, remove the `refstyle` package